# microtype: Protrusion not affecting unnumbered section titles

Tags: sectioning, microtype, protrusion

The `microtype` protrusion won't work in my starred (unnumbered) `section` titles. I have a feeling that this might be part of a general bug of `microtype` when dealing with starting lines of environments of different kinds. So I’ve tried this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13711/75284 which defines a custom `protrudeleft` command. Applying this to my MWE however has given me cryptic errors and no protrusion effect.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,factor=3500]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\section*{“Section* Title}
\noindent “Body Text
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Works for `\chapter*` (and `\chapter`.

Comment: @cfr `\chapter` is defined in `book` not `article` and the definition is via `\secdef`, rather than `\@startsection` for `\section` etc.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes. I know. I just meant that it is not to do with starred divisions *per se*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fiddled.... I have no idea what I am doing. If this breaks your document horribly, you get to keep all the itsy-bitsy pieces for yourself. I accept no responsibility if the code collaborates with your cat to order courier delivery of new tin-openers or dials out for pizza when bored.

## ***Caveat emptor...***

The basic problem, I think, is the definition of the code which initiates sections, subsections, subsubsections and paragraphs. The following code 'fixes' the issue for starred and unstarred versions of these commands.

If you customise the formatting of sections, use a non-standard class or otherwise do weird and wonderful things, this is unlikely to work. (It might. But it probably won't.)

Theoretically, it should be possible to redefine e.g. `\@section...` etc. directly, but the fixes do not work with, for example, `titlesec`.

That said:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,factor=3000]{microtype}

\makeatletter
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{% modified from latex.ltx - for starred sections below chapter level
  \@tempskipa #3\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #4{%
        \interlinepenalty \@M \noindent #5\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{#4{%
        \cfr@microfix@sec{#1}#5}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#3}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{% modified from latex.ltx - for unstarred sections below chapter level
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\cfr@microfix@sec{#3}\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\cfr@microfix@sec{#3}%
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
\newcommand*\cfr@microfix@sec[1]{%
  \ifdim#1=0pt
    \noindent
  \else
    \hskip #1\relax
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{``Charlie}
\chapter*{``Charlie}
\section{Charlie nss}
\noindent {\Large\bfseries 1.1}
\section*{``Charlie ss}
\subsection{Charlie nsss}
\subsection*{``Charlie sss}
\subsubsection{``Charlie nsss}
\subsubsection*{``Charlie ssss}

\paragraph{``Charlie np} paragraph

\paragraph*{``Charlie sp} paragraph

\subparagraph{``Charlie nsp} subparagraph

\subparagraph*{``Charlie ssp} subparagraph

\noindent{\Large\bfseries``Charlie\par}
\noindent ``Charlie
\end{document}
```

Note that in the above code `\chapter*` is included for comparison because this works out-of-the-box, and this is why I switched the class to `book`.

Here is the result:

[image: Charlie]

Note that the above solution is general: it affects protrusion generally and not just in the case of double quotes. For example, here are some examples without my preamble modification, so that protrusion is not enabled for sectional divisions:

[image: without protrusion]

Here are the same examples with my preamble, so that protrusion is enabled:

[image: with protrusion]

Although you may be unlikely to start a section heading with `(` or `<`, you might well begin with `A` or `T` or `V` or another letter for which protrusion is defined. The effect of protrusion here is more subtle, even when exaggerated as it is here, but that is the nature of micro-typography, of course: the improvements are *supposed* to be subtle ;).

Here is a comparison for `W` without the modification:

[image: without]

and with:

[image: with]

Of course, the effect is exaggerated by the protrusion factor of 3000. Here is a close up of the previous pair of images with the standard protrusion settings in place (for this font, if available). First with the standard sectioning commands:

[image: standard sectioning]

Second with the redefined versions:

[image: redefined sectioning]

So I think some *general* solution is required here, even if my attempt turns out to be an unsuitable one ;).

Comment: Perfect! Going the route of redefining the section* command seems to be more suited for the problem than fiddling with the character itself that needs to be protruded, as you showed for all the subtle protrusion of alphabetic characters.

Comment: Would it be a big hassle for you to also include a redefinement of the unstarred sectioning commands? This would help if someone wants to use hanging section numbers or if a chapter/section title runs into a second line, so the missing protrusion would be noticed there.

Comment: And another one: If I would want to customize the section title font and spacing, I see, as you predicted, that your solution doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to do these customizations without using `titlesec` or the like which would mess with this patch? At which places could I insert commands like `\large` and `vspace*{-2em}` in your patch code?

Comment: @lblb About `titlesec`: I'm about to look into this because, now you've drawn my attention to it, the issue is bothering me in everything I write! And, although I never use it, I've just decided to try `titlesec` in a class wrapper I'm developing. Hopefully, I'll have an update shortly. (If not, I'll have a new question.) About the unstarred commands: there shouldn't be a problem with the second line at all. I'm not sure about the first one without testing. Have you seen an issue with these cases?

Comment: @lblb I've added code to fix unstarred section headings for standard classes. I've not done anything specific for multi-line titles as there should be no problem with lines after the first one. I tried to disentangle `titlesec`'s code earlier but could not. I will have another go but you might consider posting that as a new question and linking to the question here for reference. Note that Ulrike  Fischer's solution *should* work with `titlesec` but it will not, of course, work for other characters unless you define suitable macros for each one. (At least, that's how I understand her answer.)

Comment: @lblb To my surprise, this works with Koma's `scrbook` as it does with `book`. `titlesec` seems to do something entirely different, though, and I'm not sure what. `memoir` does not, apparently, need a fix - it works out-of-the-box.

Comment: @lblb [New question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263391/how-can-protrusion-in-the-headings-of-document-divisions-be-fixed-when-using-pdf)...

Comment: Thank you for all the effort, I'll keep my eye on the new question you posted. If there's no good solution to be found, I will switch to `memoir`. Do you think the maintainer of `microtype` should be notified or is he already aware of this bug?

Comment: @lblb I don't think it is really a `microtype` bug. If you search, you'll find earlier discussions of protrusion problems in all kinds of different contexts and environments. As I understand it (which isn't very well), this is ultimately down to limitations in pdfTeX itself. I don't think this is something `microtype` could or should fix.

Answer (score 5):

The inner code of `\section` prevents that the protrusion can work (it inserts a box with a skip and a `\noindent`). The `\protrudeleft` command from the question you linked to imho can't work here, as it implicitly assumes that it is used in vertical mode.

You can get the protrusion with the following code.

### Attention

This is not a "general" code. It assumes that `\textquotedblleft` is defined as it is defined (and expands to the character number). I didn't test it for other encodings.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,factor=3500]{microtype}

\DeclareRobustCommand\protrudedleftquote{%
 \kern-\dimexpr\lpcode\font\textquotedblleft em/1000\relax \textquotedblleft}
 \begin{document}

\section*{“Section* Title}

\section*{\protrudedleftquote Section* Title}

“Body Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Replacing the standard definition of “ with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201C}{\protrudedleftquote}` as suggested by an edit is *not* a good idea as it will add the negative space before every quote and so break the quotes inside the running text. The command `\protrudedleftquote` should only be used at the begin of lines.

Comment: Thank you! To make it clear your command will use the correct `microtype` protrusion setting, so it's a good solution.

Comment: @lblb: I removed your edit as the code was wrong. It will add negative spaces in places where you don't want it. Try out `“Body “Text`.

Comment: @lblb Isn't the problem a more general one, though? Protrusion is not broken only for sectional headings beginning with double quote marks.