# Spacing of brackets with unicode-math

Tags: spacing, unicode-math

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}

\begin{document}
\textit{f}(\textit{q})
$f(q_i,p_i,t)
\left[ \int df \right]$
\end{document}
```

This uses *Linux Libertine* for many math characters, but the brackets are still taken from *XITS Math* and therefore the spacing is bad (the 'f' collides with the bracket).

How can I use the brackets from *Linux Libertine* in math mode? Additionally, is it possible to get the brackets that adjust to their content (like '\right]') from *Linux Libertine* as well?

Edit: To clarify, the example shows that the spacing is correct in textmode, but fails in mathmode. I wonder why this is the case and how it may be fixed.

Comment: You could manually add a thinspace `\,` to add the additional space. And it seems that the brackets already do auto adjust their height as you have it.

Comment: Does this question on [italic correction for linux libertine font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/italic-correction-for-linux-libertine-font) help?

Comment: This happens with other fonts as well, so the issue is not specific to Linux Libertine.

Comment: No idea for a fix. LaTeX does not kern between different fonts. This is why unicode-math will produce different spacing between certain characters compared to regular T1 math.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an automatic way to fix this, but adding a manual thinspace (`\,`) seems to work (run with `XeLaTeX`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}

\begin{document}
\textit{f}(\textit{q})
$f\,(q_i,p_i,t)
\left[ \int df \,\right]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but I'm more interested in fixing this globally.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following additional definition:

```
\setmathfont[range=\lbrace] {Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\rbrace] {Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\lparen] {Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\rparen] {Linux Libertine O}
```

This does not work well with *italics*, however.