# Capital letter expanded letter space kerning

Tags: microtype, kerning, letterspacing

I am using the following code

```
\usepackage{microtype,textcase}
\textls*[110]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Specialties}}}
```

I would like to achieve even letter spacing.  Unfortunately, the kerning of the "ALT" is not good.  Is there any way to make this better (even spacing)?

Edit: One thing that improves the letter spacing between the L and T is to do

```
\usepackage{microtype,textcase}
\textls*[110]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Specia{l}{t}ies}}}
```

but the A and the L are still too far apart.  Also, I am using this code as a command with the "Specialties" part being an argument.  It would be nice to have a solution to make the letter spacing even without having to do tricks like this.

Comment: Something you could try is adjusting the kerning between L and T with `SetExtraKerning` as in mhp's answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/space-between-emphasized-word-and-parenthesis/25929#25929

Answer (score 5):

Although "not good" may be very subjective, I would suggest encompassing any faulty kerning letters with `{.}`. This should reduce or eliminate the automatic effects of kerning.

Another letter spacing alternative is provided by the [`soul` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul). The following minimal example illustrates the differences/similarities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{soul}

\sodef\myspace{}{.2em}{1em plus1em}{2em plus.1em minus.1em}% User-defined letter spacing

\begin{document}

\textls*[110]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Special{t}ies}}}

\so{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Specialties}}}

\myspace{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Special{t}ies}}}

\end{document}​
```

[image: Different letter spacing techniques]

Comment: I was using the soul package initially but switched to microtype; they seem to give similar results.  Putting a letter in `{.}` helps a lot.  Out of curiosity, is there any way to take an argument `specialties` and convert it to `{S}{P}{E}{C}{I}{A}{L}{T}{I}{E}{S}`?

Answer (score 4):

Here I introduce the routine `\spaceout[added space]{string}` to indicate text to be spaced out.  The optional argument can specify the extra space added between each letter of the argument (here I default it to 0.5pt).  Spaces are properly parsed in the argument, using similar logic to my answer at [How to bold custom calligraphic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194241/how-to-bold-custom-calligraphic-text/194273#194273).

In my MWE here, I show how `\spaceout` can be used both to compress or expand text spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \def\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\parskip 1ex
\usepackage{microtype,textcase}
\begin{document}

\textls*[110]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Specialties}}}  OP\#1

\textls*[110]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Specia{l}{t}ies}}}  OP\#2

\textls*[110]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Speci\spaceout[-.6pt]{alt}ies}}} \verb|\spaceout|

\vspace{3ex}
test test test test test test  no spacing

test \spaceout{test test test test} test  0.5pt added spacing

test \spaceout[1.5pt]{test test test test} test  1.5pt added spacing

test \spaceout[5pt]{test test test test} test  5pt added spacing
\end{document}
```

[image]

And below, we see an example on bold sans caps:

[image]

which uses the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \def\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries
THIS IS MY HEADING  \tabto{2.5in}no added spacing

\spaceout{THIS IS MY HEADING}  \tabto{2.5in}0.5pt added spacing

\spaceout[1.5pt]{THIS IS MY HEADING}  \tabto{2.5in}1.5pt added spacing

\spaceout[3pt]{THIS IS MY HEADING}  \tabto{2.5in}3pt added spacing
\end{document}
```