# How to bold custom handwritten text

Tags: environments, bold

I use the **miama** font to simulate short (a couple of lines) handwritten pieces of text.
As the font is rather light, I use an adaption of **Steven B. Segletes** solution from
[How to bold custom calligraphic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194241/how-to-bold-custom-calligraphic-text)

1. The problem is, that giving `\BODY` as `\calbf` argument, it swallows all line breaking. (But it handles
   UTF-8 chars with german Umlauts etc. well). This has nothing to do with the miama font. Line breaking is affected also without it.
2. I also wonder about the fact that calling `\calbf` as shown in the last (outcommented) line, it
   raises this error:

   ! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

   See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
   Type  H   for immediate help.
    ...

   l.61 ...á é ó í ú \ldots \"e \"i \"a \"o \"u}
   enter code here

Can someone show me how to handle (especially) issue 1?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[scale=1]{miama}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\def\calup{.2pt}
\def\calover{.15pt}
\def\calbf#1{\calbfhelpA#1 \relax\relax}
\def\calbfhelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \calbfhelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \calbfhelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\calbfhelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \stackon[\calup]{#1}{\kern\calover#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \calbfhelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}

\NewEnviron{MyCal}%
{%
  \fmmfamily%
  \noindent%
  \calbf{Test0}\\ \BODY \\\\ \calbf{\BODY}%
}

\begin{document}
\def\calup{.3pt}
\def\calover{.3pt}


\begin{MyCal}
MyCal:\\
Test1: ä.ö.ü.Ä.Ö.Ü.ß.\ss.
\par
á é ó í ú

\"e \"i \"a \"o \"u
\end{MyCal}
\par\vspace{1em}
%\calbf{ä.ö.ü.Ä.Ö.Ü.ß.\ss \ldots  á é ó í ú \ldots \"e \"i \"a \"o \"u}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for issue 1. I don't understand enough about issue 2 to try to resolve it.

The main issue was that the original version of `\calbf` had no handling of expansion at all. So what happened was that `\calbf` saw a single token `\BODY` and just passed it through and said `\stackon[\calup]{\BODY}{\kern\calover\BODY}`. The reason that `\calbf` tries to pass one token to `\calup` at a time is presumably due to the fact that passing a whole block of text destroys line breaking.

So changing `\calbf` to expand its argument helps. I use the `\romannumeral` trick to recursively expand the first token of `\calbfhelpA`. In this case, the first token is `\BODY` and it expands and dumps out the rest of everything.

Another issue then arises which is that the only reason it worked to say `\"a` before was because `\calbf` wasn't successfully separating out individual characters of the input because it was all in `\BODY`. The fix requires testing inside of `\calbfhelpB` whether the first argument is a macro. If the first argument is a macro, save it and grab the next token as well. We also run into trouble if we see a `\par` or `\\` token, so we test for those separately.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[scale=1]{miama}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\def\calup{.2pt}
\def\calover{.15pt}

\makeatletter
% Terminal token to signal end of input.
% We give it a unique definition so that `\ifx\endtoken\anythingelse` always tests false.
% Since we're using fexpansion, we need an extra `\noexpand` to prevent it from getting
% turned into something else.
\def\calbf@endtoken{\noexpand\calbf@endtoken}

% Use \romannumeral trick to "f expand" argument
% We are going to parse by spaces, so we need to add a terminal space and \relax
% so we can tell when we are done.
\def\calbf#1{\expandafter\calbf@\romannumeral-`0#1 \calbf@endtoken}

% Needs to be \long in case argument is a \par token.
% #1 - a single word
\long\def\calbf@#1 {%
  \calbf@handleword{}#1\calbf@endtoken
  % Check if we are done. If not, fexpand rest of input and recurse.
  \@ifnextchar\calbf@endtoken{}{\ \expandafter\calbf@\romannumeral-`0}%
}

% Helper macro to test for equality.
\long\def\calbf@ifx#1#2{%
    \ifx#1#2\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}

% Test if argument is a macro (checks if \string#1 contains multiple characters).
\long\def\calbf@ifmacro#1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\expandafter$\romannumeral-`0\expandafter\@gobble\string#1$%
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
}

\long\def\calbf@handleword#1#2{%
  \calbf@ifx{#2}{\calbf@endtoken}{}{% we're done with this word
  \calbf@ifx{#2}{\par}{%
    #2\calbf@handleword{}% just pass \par tokens through
  }{%
  \calbf@ifx{#2}{\\}{%
    #2\calbf@handleword{}% just pass \\ tokens through
  }{%
    \calbf@ifmacro#2{% If it's an accent, save it and grab the argument too.
        \calbf@handleword{#1#2}%
    }{%
        \stackon[\calup]{#1{#2}}{\kern\calover#1{#2}}% Otherwise print it.
        \calbf@handleword{}%
    }%
  }}}%
}

\NewEnviron{MyCal}{%
  %\fmmfamily
  \noindent
  \calbf{Test0}\\ \BODY \\\\
  \calbf{\BODY}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\def\calup{.3pt}
\def\calover{.3pt}


\"{ab}

\begin{MyCal}
 MyCal:\\
Test1: %ä.ö.ü.Ä.Ö.Ü.ß.\ss.
\par
abcd

\"e \"i \"a \"o \"u \"e\"i\"a\"o\"u \"{abcd} {1234}
\end{MyCal}
\par\vspace{1em}
%\calbf{ä.ö.ü.Ä.Ö.Ü.ß.\ss \ldots  á é ó í ú \ldots \"e \"i \"a \"o \"u}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works also for `Test1: ä.ö.ü.Ä.Ö.Ü.ß.\ss`. uncommented. But ` MyCal:\\ ` produces **MyCal:=* **

Comment: You're saying it strips a leading space?

Comment: No. I wanted to say that it raises this error: `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` And after pressing 'q' it produces the output with MyCal:=*

Comment: @Jack I think I fixed that error.

Comment: Yes, you did. But now the line `ä.ö.ü.Ä.Ö.Ü.ß.` produces an error. So I am still looking for improvement. But thanks for your efforts.