# Changing word spacing in section headers

Tags: spacing, sectioning

**Background** In a draft book, I am using `cabin` [scaled to 0.93] as my sans-serif font both for text and for some math symbols. The font for section-headings is defined by `\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright}` (in a `memoir` class document).

**The issue** I am quite happy with the look of the book, except that the word-spacing in section-headings looks *very* slightly too cramped. (Running heads, also in sans-serif, but at normal size, look fine to me as they are.)

**The question(s)** Is there a way to increase the word spacing of text set in  `\Large\sffamily` while leaving other sans serif text untouched? (The current letter spacing is fine, and I don't want to change that.)

Failing that, what is the simplest way to increase the word spacing of text set in `\sffamily` while leaving the spacing of mathematics set in sans serif untouched?

Minimal example to work with ...

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright}
\usepackage[scaled=0.93]{cabin}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\section{This heading could do with marginally more word spacing}
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a pinch, maybe something like this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/capital-letter-expanded-letter-space-kerning, would help.

Comment: Please post a minimum working example. Incidentally, do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I'm using pdfTeX via TeXShop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can locally over-ride the font specified interword space by setting `\spaceskip`, normally in the preamble, wherever you specified the section head font, but here mid document for comparison purposes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{The Cat Sat On The Mat}
Zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\spaceskip1cm}}
\makeatother

\section{The Cat Sat On The Mat}
Zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz


\end{document}
```

Comment: This gives a neatly minimalist solution -- thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your `memoir` document, you may achieve your objective by loading the `microtype` package in the preamble and changing

```
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright}
```

to

```
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright\textls[50]}
```

Feel free to modify the argument of `\textls` to suit your needs. (The default value of the optional argument is `100`. I think that leads to overly loose-looking letterspacing; that's why I suggest starting with `50`.)

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{microtype} % for '\textls' macro
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright\textls[50]}
\usepackage[scaled=0.93]{cabin}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\section{The quick brown fox jumps}
\lipsum[2] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this changes letter spacing, and -- though I've edited the question to make it clearer -- I did initially say that the current letter spacing is fine: it is just the word spacing I want to alter, by a small percentage.