# Problems with insert_before and post_linebreak_filter

Tags: errors, luatex, lua

I'm coding an algorithm to detect and highlight [homeoarchies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27588/repetition-of-a-word-on-two-lines).

Here my current almost working (but compiling at least) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage{luatexbase}
 \usepackage{luacode}
 \begin{luacode}
 compare_lines = function (line1,line2)
   local head1 = line1.head
   local head2 = line2.head

   local char_count = 0
   local word_count = 0

   while (head1.id == 37 and head2.id == 37
          and head1.char == head2.char)          -- identical glyph
      or (head1.id == 10 and head2.id == 10) do  -- glue

      if (head1.id == 37) then -- glyph
         char_count = char_count + 1
      elseif (head1.id == 10) then -- glue
         word_count = word_count + 1
      end
      head1 = head1.next
      head2 = head2.next
   end
   return char_count,word_count,head1,head2
 end

 homeoarchy = function ( head )
   local cur_line = head
   local prev_line -- initiate prev_head

   local max_char = 3
   local max_word = 1

   while head do
     if head.id == 0 then -- new line
       print("new line")
       prev_line = cur_line
       cur_line = head
       if prev_line.id == 0 then
          char_count,word_count,prev_head,cur_head = compare_lines(prev_line,cur_line)
          if char_count >= max_char or word_count >= max_word then
             w1_prev = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
             w1_prev.data = "q 1 0 1 rg"
             w1_prev.mode = 1

             w2_prev = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
             w2_prev.data = "Q"
             w2_prev.mode = 1

             node.insert_before(prev_line,prev_line.head.next,w1_prev)
             node.insert_before(prev_line,prev_head,w2_prev)

             w1_cur = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
             w1_cur.data = "q 1 0 1 rg"
             w1_prev.mode = 1

             w2_cur = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
             w2_cur.data = "Q"
             w2_cur.mode = 1

             node.insert_before(cur_line,cur_line.head.next,w1_cur)
             node.insert_before(cur_line,cur_head,w2_cur)

             print("done placing markers")
          end
       end
     end
     head = head.next
   end
       return true
 end

 luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",homeoarchy,"homeoarchy")
 \end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{1.7in}
Je suis venu non pour juger le monde, mais pour sauver le monde. Celui qui me rejette
et qui ne re\c coit pas mes
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{1.7in}
Je suis venu non pour juger~le monde, mais pour sauver le monde. Celui qui me rejette
et qui ne re\c coit pas mes
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{1.7in}
Je suis venu non pour juger le monde, mais pour sauver~le monde. Celui qui me rejette
et qui ne re\c coit pas mes
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{1.6in}
Je suis venu non pour juger le monde, mais pour sauver le monde. Celui qui me rejette
et qui ne re\c coit pas mes
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{1.8in}
Je suis venu non pour juger le monde, mais pour sauver le monde. Celui qui me rejette
et qui ne re\c coit pas mes
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: two bugs to go]

It's easy to spot two bugs here:

- the color starts after the "l" instead of before it. I've tried all sorts of combinations, from "prev_line.head" to "prev_line.head.next.prev", and I always get an error saying I can't insert before a non-existing node. I'm pretty sure the "l" node does exist. How can I insert before it?
- the text stops after the second colored word. So I've colored the words alright, but I'd still like the rest of the text... How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several non-obvious problems in the code. It's really tricky!

- `node.insert_before(prev_line,prev_line.head.next,w1_prev)`. You should never use `insert_before` without assigning the `new_head` return value, for the second argument could be the beginning of the list and inserting something before will require a new head pointer.
- The `whatsit`/`pdf_literal` trick is not really suitable for running text, but don't ask me for a perfect solution. I use pdf colorstacks from pdftex, but these will probably break in a lot of situations (`vsplit` and alike). If you have a look at the generated pdf (use [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) to view it) you will find out that the text is in the PDF, but not visible.

---

```
...
1 0 0 1 148.712 674.423 Tm [(jette)-204(et)-205(qui)-205(ne)-204(rec)383<b8>-70(oit)-205(pas)-204(mes)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 652.062 Tm [(J)31(e)-507(suis)-508(v)17(en)15(u)-506(non)-508(pour)-507(ju-)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 640.106 Tm [(g)15(er)-640(le)-641(monde,)-642(mais)-640(pour)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 628.151 Tm [(sa)16(uv)18(er)-363(le)-363(monde.)-363(C)5(el)15(ui)-362(qui)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 616.196 Tm [(me)-453(rejette)-454(et)-453(qui)-454(ne)-453(rec)383<b8>-70(oit)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 604.241 Tm [(pas)-255(mes)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 581.969 Tm [(J)31(e)-301(suis)-301(v)17(en)15(u)-300(non)-301(pour)-301(jug)14(er)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 570.014 Tm [(le)-527(monde,)-527(mais)-527(pour)-527(sa)15(u-)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 558.059 Tm [(v)18(er)-317(le)-318(monde.)-317(C)5(el)15(ui)-317(qui)-317(me)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 546.104 Tm [(rejette)-422(et)-423(qui)-423(ne)-423(rec)383<b8>-70(oit)-422(pas)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 534.149 Tm [(mes)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 514.313 Tm [(J)31(e)-363(suis)-363(v)17(en)15(u)-362(non)-363(pour)-363(ju-)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 502.358 Tm [(g)15(er)-460(le)-460(monde,)-461(mais)-460(pour)]TJ
1 0 0 1 148.712 490.403 Tm [(sa)16(uv)18(er)-729(le)-729(monde.)-732(C)5(el)15(ui)]TJ
...
```

Comment: thanks. Does the answer I provided fix the `insert_before` issue properly?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fix for the first bug already:

By replacing `node.insert_before(prev_line,prev_line.head.next,w1_prev` with `node.insert_after(prev_line.prev,prev_line.prev,w1_prev)`, I got it to work.

The second but is that I had `w1_prev.mode = 1` instead of `w1_cur.mode = 1`...

Comment: `prev_line` looks like a hlist to me, so `prev_line.prev` could be a penalty or a glue or even nil - this doesn't look right. It should probably be `prev_line.head`.