# white lines in paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, typography, hyphenation

I need the pdf resulting from my compilation to show all the spaces occupied by the characters with a gray background, the goal I am pursuing is to visualize the white lines that form between words in the paragraph on the page.

The idea is to be able to observe on the page the typographic quality of the printing ink stain.

Someone can help me

Comment: It doesn't do what you ask but the inverse (highlighting the rivers not the text) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29007/1090

Comment: I use the impnattypo package with the rivers function, what I'm looking for is just. I imagine it on the side of printing the boxes containing the characters instead of the character itself and thus obtain the visual effect

Comment: You may like the `colorstretch` function of `chickenize`.