# Two letter variable names

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

In math mode, TeX assumes "hidden multiplication" (so that two variable names put nearby have invisible multiplication between), so that, AFAICT, expressions like `$ABC$` are rendered with small distances between letters.
Now, what to do if I have a two-letter variable name, like for instance TP or FN (true positive or false negative)? Leave as they are? Put them in `\text`? Yet in the first option they will look like T*P or F*N and in the second one they will differentiate from one-letter symbols.

In optics, the 2-letter variable *NA* is used for numerical aperture.

Comment: I think that for a two-letter variable name, you *should* use an upright font to make it clear that it is not a product of two variables.

Comment: @Jukka: I think it depends. In this case I'm not sure if TP is a variable name; if not, then I'd say an upright font is indeed the better choice. I myself don't use two letter _variables_, but if I would, then I'd probably use the math italic font.

Comment: `\mathrm{TP}` can be used for an upright font

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You would write `\mathit{TP}` or `\mathit{FN}`. If you're going to do this frequently, you can make macros for them.

```
\newcommand\TP{\mathit{TP}}
\newcommand\FN{\mathit{FN}}
```

Comment: @TH.: This has the disadvantage that the text italic font is used, not the math italic one.

Comment: @Hendrik: This is only a disadvantage when the two fonts use different glyphs for a given character. It has the advantage of using the appropriate font kerning table for the letters rather than relying on the user to guess at intercharacter spacing.

Comment: @TH.: I only thought of the CM fonts. There different glyphs are used for text and math italic; that's why my comment. There's no denying the advantage of automatic spacing, though.

Comment: +1. However, I much prefer the convention that entities with multicharacter names be typeset in roman, not italic. `\mathit` is good for stuff like “the triangle TUV”, though.

Comment: If using `\mathit` you should add `\ensuremath`

Comment: @Seamus: I disagree. When writing mathematical material, I find it best to make that obvious in the source by explicitly adding the math shift characters (or their equivalents).

Comment: @Seamus — My opinion vacillates on this. My current theory is that macros that are to be used in math mode should still require explicit markup to show they're "maths entities": e.g., I think `where $\RE$ is the Reynolds number` is slightly better.

Comment: @TH @Will So, when I have `\ensuremath` in a macro, and I try and use it outside of mathmode, it still breaks. In fact, I'm not even sure what it does, I just thought you were supposed to put it in macros that are mathmode specific...

Comment: I've been using `\ensuremath` wrong. I see how it works now. I'm still not sure I see why adding superfluous dollars all over your text is helpful...

Comment: @Seamus: It's a visual indicator that you're typesetting math. In many cases, it works out to one extra character. To take Will's example, `where \RE\ is the reynolds number` seems worse to me. Still, `\ensuremath` works and there's no harm in having it.

Comment: @TH., @Seamus: Just to weigh in with my 2øre.  I use `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` so that I can type stuff like "Let \R be the real numbers".  Since I would use `\(` and `\)` (not dollars), it saves me four characters, and as for visual indicators, I rather prefer to keep the flow of the sentence.

Comment: Right, all — I'm certainly not saying that using `\ensuremath` like this is wrong, it's more a matter of taste in how you like your markup.

Comment: Defining this command does not change the space between the letters, while `\newcommand\TP{T\!P}` works well, as in Hendrik's answer.

Answer (score 35):

I guess that the best solution is to define a macro with manually adjusted negative space, e.g.

```
\newcommand\TP{T\!P}
```

or with `\hspace{-0.1em}` instead of `\!`. You can also use the [`\ric` command from this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71065) to remove the space after the `T`. (Then you won't have to guess the amount of negative space, but the result is not always satisfactory.)

---

*As there's been some debate about this answer, let me provide more detail:*

It is not the case that TeX puts space between the letters in math mode, but after each letter it puts the italic correction for the letter. There are ways to see what's happening, and both are a bit steep.

**First possibility:**
On a console, run

```
tex '\tracingall $TP$ \bye'
```

If you are on a unix like system, better run

```
tex '\tracingall $TP$ \bye' | sed -n '/mathon/,/mathoff/p'
```

Then in the terminal output you'll find the lines

```
...\mathon
...\teni T
...\kern1.3889
...\teni P
...\kern1.3889
...\mathoff
```

The `\tracingall` command is telling TeX to, well, leave a trace of everything it's doing. The first 3 of these lines tell you the following: Math mode is entered, the letter `T` in font `\teni` (10pt math font `cmmi10`) is typeset, and then a kern of 1.3889(pt) is put after the `T`. This is exactly the italic correction of the `T`. *How do I know this?* On a unix system that's easy: Run

```
tftopl $(kpsewhich cmmi10.tfm) | grep 'CHARACTER C T' -A3
```

(`tfm` means "TeX font metric") and you'll get the terminal output

```
(CHARACTER C T
   (CHARWD R 0.584376)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   (CHARIC R 0.13889)
```

This tells you the following about the character `T` in the font `cmmi10`: It has a width of 0.584376, a height of 0.683332 and an italic correction of 0.13889, all measured in pt.

The same applies to the lines above starting with `...\teni P`; the letter `P` has the same italic correction, and then mathmode is turned off. Though this looks convincing, it doesn't *prove* that the `\kern1.3889` provided by `\tracingall` comes from the italic correction. If you want to be fully convinced, then there is no other choice than to read Appendix G of the TeXbook *really extremely carefully*, which I regard the steeper path.

**Second possibility:**

Read Appendix G of the TeXbook. Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I'd call easy reading. You get a first approximation of
the insertion of the italic correction on page 441:

> We frequently need to execute a subroutine called “Set box `x` to the so-and-so field in style such-and-such.” This means (a) ... (b) if the field contains a symbol, `x` is set to an hbox containing that symbol in the appropriate size, and the italic correction for the character is included in the width of the box; ...

In the current circumstances, e.g. the letter `T` is such a symbol that is put into the box `x`, *together with its italic correction*. However, this is not the full truth. There is one circumstance where TeX doesn't insert the italic correction: In Rule 17 on page 445 it says

> If the symbol was not marked by Rule 14 above as a text symbol, or if `\fontdimen` parameter number 2 of its font is zero, set δ to the italic correction; otherwise set δ to zero.

We don't have to care about Rule 14 and text symbols. Why? One important feature of a math font is that its `\fontdimen` parameter number 2 is zero. For `cmmi10`, you can convince yourself by typing

```
tftopl $(kpsewhich cmmi10.tfm) | grep FONTDIMEN -A2
```

which yields the output

```
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.25)
   (SPACE R 0.0)
```

and you see that the second parameter `SPACE` is indeed zero. This makes sense: As every novice in TeX and friends has to learn, spaces don't get typeset in math mode.

Comment: I don't think it's italic correction between the letters — the math font is an entirely separate font with different inherent spacing. Using `\mathit` is the correct approach here.

Comment: @Will: Probably you didn't expect this when you posted this comment, but it got 5 upvotes so far although it is incorrect; see also the edit to [this post of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3490/1235). (It even got me one downvote; although I don't care about the rep, I don't think that this answer deserves a downvote.) I don't deny that there are reasons for using `\mathit` (see my comments to TH's answer), but I do think that the approach is not entirely correct here.

Comment: I don't think you're correct about the italic correction. See rule 14. In particular `$TP$` should have two Ord atoms. The rule is applicable since the nucleus of the first  is a symbol, the subscript and superscript are empty, the next item is an Ord, and its nucleus is a symbol in the same family. The first Ord is marked as a text symbols. The font's kern information is used to insert a kern between the two Ords. On to Rule 17. Typeset the nucleus in the current style. Delta is set to 0 since it was marked. No italic correction is inserted. On to Rule 18 which has nothing to do.

Comment: Continuing. Rule 2 applies for the kern that got inserted, but there's nothing more to do so we move on to the final Ord. Once again, Rule 14 applies. In this case, there is no next item in the math list so we go to Rule 17. It gets typeset in the current style. It was not marked in Rule 14, so delta gets set to the italic correction. If delta is nonzero, a kern of width delta is inserted. Rule 18 again has nothing more to do. The next item (if it exists) is the italic correction kern. It's processed in Rule 2 (by doing nothing). In the end, we should get two boxes (T, P) and 0, 1, or 2 kerns.

Comment: The space is at my opinion the italic correction. The interesting question is why it is not inserted when you use `\mathit`. This is answered in Appendix F: fontdimen 7 (extra space) of cmmiXX is 0pt and "this is the mark of a font that is intended only for mathematical typesetting; the rules in Appendix G state that the italic correction is added between adjacent characters from such fonts."

Comment: @TH., @Ulrike: In Rule 17 it says: "If the symbol was not marked by Rule 14 above as a text symbol, _or if `\fontdimen` parameter number 2 of its font is zero_, set $\delta$ to the italic correction; otherwise set $\delta$ to zero" (emphasis added by me). Yes, the symbol `T` was marked as a text symbol, _but it is from a math font, i.e., `\fontdimen2` is 0_.

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah yes. I saw that when I was writing those comments, but I didn't check what the value of `\fontdimen2` actually was. Looks like I should have done so. That said, shouldn't changing `\fontdimen2\textfont0` to be nonzero remove the italic correction? It doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: @TH.: You should change `\fontdimen2\textfont1` to something nonzero; then `$TP$` becomes OK, but `$PT$` becomes awful. The math fonts are not designed for that.

Comment: I can't understand a word, so I can't tell if it is a good idea or not; yet `\mathit` solution worked for me, so I accepted TH.'s answer.

Comment: @mbq: It's quite OK that you accepted TH's answer, it has definitely some advantages. I'll add some more explanation to my answer later.

Comment: @TH.: Thanks for reminding me of Rule 17. I've included this bit in my explanation above.

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah ha! I was confusing the family with the character class. No matter how many times I read Appendix G and Chapter 17, I find it confusing. (Actually, I wish all of the double dangerous bend material in Chapter 17 were just collected in Appendix G.) But back to the question at hand, one problem with using manual spacing is you lose out on ligatures.

Comment: @TH.: No problem here (for the CM fonts) as there are no ligatures in `cmmi`, as `tftopl $(kpsewhich cmmi10.tfm) | grep LIG` reveals. (Try the same command with `cmmi` replaced by `cmr`.)

Comment: @Will: Please tell me if I'm being obtrusive, but somehow I'd expected some kind of reaction from you (an upvote would be appreciated `:-)`). Of course you're right that the math fonts have different inherent spacing, but an important part of the story is the italic correction.

Comment: @Hendrik not at all, i appreciate the explanations. Just been overworked recently :-)

Comment: @Hendrik: The lack of ligatures is exactly the problem. A variable named `effect` would look pretty bad without them, I think.

Comment: @TH.: Ah, OK, now I know what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for mentioning \!. Very usefull when defining variable increases with a capital delta, like $\Delta\!v$.