# Ugly spacing around f in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

My paper contains many math expressions like `$abcde$` or `$abdefv$`.  Unfortunately, the latter looks very ugly, particularly in regards to the spacing around the `f`.  In particular, there is a significant amount of space around the `f` which is not present around the other letters.

Is there a method to make that spacing tighter?

*Note*: Joseph Wright suggested using `\!` to get a negative thin space.  This does seem to help.  But I'm still a bit curious as to why the problem occurs at all.  For example, it looks fine in `$acdfv$` before the `f` but not after.  If anyone has some more details on why the spacing ends up as it does, please comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a very unlikely product - do you really mean this? If so, perhaps try `\!` to back the spacing up.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Yes, that's an actual example from my paper, but $efv$ has the same problem and isn't as unlikely.  Thanks for the $\!$ advice -- I guess I should have thought about that.  That works before the $f$ quite well.  Is there a predefined way to get an even thinner negative space (for after the $f$) or should I use $\hspace{-..}$?

Comment: Sounds like tensor calculus, which leads to, as Spivak calls it in his differential geometry tome, "The debauch of indicies."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For a detailed answer *why* this is happening you can read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/two-letter-variable-names/6089#6089) of mine (shameless plug indeed): In short, the italic correction of the `f` has a great part in this. But the italic correction only explains the spacing *after* the `f`, not *before*. For this you have to look at the bounding boxes of the letters:

[image]

The first `f` is a text italic letter in its bounding box, the second one is math italic (in its bounding box together with its italic correction). As you can see, the text letter protrudes a bit to the left (and a lot to the right); the math letter has a tiny bit of white space in the left (and also in the right, because of the italic correction). For a bit more about the bounding boxes see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3490/1235) of mine (another shameless plug `:-)`).

I first noticed the problem when typing `$Vf$`, which doesn't yield a nice output. My resort is using `$V\hspace{-0.1em}f$` instead (in a macro, of course), which I like much better. You could even use `$V\!f$`, but this I find too narrow. Compare these three:

[image]    
[image]    
[image]

I would *not* encourage you to follow Caramdir's (now removed) suggestion to use `$\mathit{Vf}$` since this uses a different font (text italic, not math italic). You can see quite clearly that the `V` is narrower (in other words, the angle at the bottom of the `V` is more acute):

[image]

If you use a different math font (like Euler), then the difference is even more noticeable.

(For a case where `\textit` could be a good solution, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/two-letter-variable-names/6088#6088) of TH.)

Answer (score 4):

Math mode considers each symbol a separate variable, not part of a "word". If you want word-like behaviour, use `\mathrm{...}` or `\mathit{...}`. If this really is a product, perhaps using `\cdot` between factors (or reorganizing, or changing variable names, perhaps distinguished by subindices) helps.