# How to trim space around italic `f` in unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, stix2

I am making (almost) my first attempt with unicode-math and this is my first use of the STIXTwo fonts. I'm unhappy with the spacing around italic `f` in math mode. (And with the spacing before italic `j` in some cases.)  I'm using Lualatex (up-to-date TL2021) and STIXTwo fonts from their Github site.

Can I adjust this somehow (in Latex, I have no font editor)?  If so, will I need to specify an adjustment for every pair?  I found this link, [Change kerning for `f'` in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255098/change-kerning-for-f-in-math-mode) , but it did not help. This link ([Two letter variable names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/two-letter-variable-names)) suggests that the problem is italic correction, and this one ([Ugly spacing around f in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6819/ugly-spacing-around-f-in-math-mode)) indicates that the problem is with a math-mode bounding box. (Can I *adjust* that box?)

If it's possible, could someone show me the syntax of how to adjust a pair or two, so that I can go do others? (And if it's possible to just modify `f` itself or its "bounding box" instead of a bunch of pairs, that would of course be terrific.)

Here's an expression taken from the first link above that I think produces ugly output with unicode-math+STIXTwo:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}

\begin{document}
\[ \frac{2\pi ft}{k} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: `unicode-math` loads `fontspec`, so no need to load it manually.

Comment: In ConTeXt this is possible via so-called goodie files. I don't know if there is a counterpart for LaTeX. But, are you sure you want to do this? Try for example `e_2f^b`. There is not too much space to take.

Comment: The more I look at the formula, the more I see the necessity of the italic correction.

Comment: @mickep So it looks like I would need to specify specific pairs, maybe just other letters after and letters and digits before.  But is that _possible_?

Comment: As far as I know, configuring the kerning between specific pairs in math is not doable. But is this the true formula (it looks like the one in the question you linked to), or do you have some other real-life example where it looks worse?

Comment: This particular formula was copied from that other page.  But `2πf` is angular frequency (ω) and is common. And thus `2πft` is angle. You also see a fair bit of `df/dt` in signals work. If it's known that math kerning is not possible, I'd accept that as an answer (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

You can kern.

Here I use `\!\,`:

[image: italic f]

I don't have STIX2, but TexGyrePagella shows the same.

MWE

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular}
%\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}
\setmainfont{TexGyrePagella}
\setmathfont{TexGyrePagellaMath}

\begin{document}
\[ \frac{2\pi ft}{k} \]
\[ \frac{2\pi f\!\,t}{k} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do `texdoc latex2e`, "16.6 Spacing in math mode", might help.

Comment: With a macro solution, I would need to use it every time I use an `f`.  I was hoping I could set something up once and get it over with.

Comment: Just an aside, you likely have an older STIXTwo available, looks like both Texlive 2020 and 2021, at least, came with it: `texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix2-otf/STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf`

Comment: Latex2e manual says: `One advantage of these commands is that they automatically insert italic corrections if
needed (see Section 19.9 [\/], page 163). Specifically, they insert the italic correction unless
the following character is in the list \nocorrlist, which by default consists of a period
and a comma. To suppress the automatic insertion of italic correction, use \nocorr at the
start or end of the command argument, such as \textit{\nocorr text} or \textsc{text
\nocorr}.` and `There is no concept of italic correction in math mode; spacing is done in a different way.`

Comment: Would redefining `unicode-maths` `\mitf` macro be worthwhile: `\UnicodeMathSymbol{"1D453}{\mitf                     }{\mathalpha}{mathematical italic small f}%` (`unicode-math-table.tex` line 1535), or maybe defining a new symbol instead? However, *some* correction *must* be needed for italic f anyway, because of its lean: that is, see what `f{}` does.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Redefine `\mitf` to what?

In any case, looks like macros are the way to go, since no one seems to think spacing can be done another way.

Do tables of kerning pairs even exist in the fonts for math mode? Or is that a text mode thing only?

Comment: (a) Redefine math italic f to cancel out italic correction. (b) kerning tables for maths - ask a separate question. Also, lua code could handle it. But wouldn't it be an open-ended set, since it's not only symbol x symbol, but also symbol x operator (plus user-defined symbols and operators). Possible, since the standard glyphs are all in the Math unicode blocks in the (unicode) font. Lot of work: ~1000 x 256 pairings. (c) Italic correction was done for a purpose; removing it will make things "wrong" to others. (d) You are in effect asking to design your own ligature(s), at the limit.

Comment: I believe that both (a) and (b, if it can be done in Latex) are _this_ question. I don't  understand how to do either. But I'm not in for 1000x256, of course.  Just `f` paired with a few others.  If that's not possible, I'm out-of-luck, but will accept that as an answer.