# Math letter's italic correction

Tags: fonts, math-mode, italic-correction

Are there a way to display `PS` and `TN` and `CD` and so forth (product of two variables) more beautifully? The normal CM font puts a wide space between the left letter and right letter.

[image]

If use the package `txfonts` the `$S_1$` turned not so good-looking.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've nothing to do with `txfonts` (more exactly, `txmi` family). Maybe you can use another Times like font package. `mathptmx` works fine (but it has fewer symbols than `txfonts`), and if you use XeTeX, you can also use XITS Math for math fonts. Commercial fonts like MathTimePro(2) are also good-looking.

I suggest XITS Math with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
See $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Leo Liu has answered about subscripts: unfortunately, the tx fonts have some design flaws.

Regarding the space between letters in math mode, that's a design decision by Knuth. The simple juxtaposition of two letters means usually the product of two variables (or parameters). If you need "multiletter identifiers", then use

```
$\mathit{AB}\mathit{CD}$.
```

Comment: `$\textit{AB}\textit{CD}$.` in comparison has no space between the B and the C (apparently *italic correction* for `\textit` is deactivated in math mode). But forcing italic correction with `$\texthit{AB\/}\textit{CD}$.` gives the same output as `$\mathit{AB}\mathit{CD}$`. Is it because `\mathit` applies italic correction **with** a *multiletter* argument?

Comment: @Maggyero In math mode TeX applies automatically the italic correction in well determined situations. The addition is done only at the end of the subformula, so with `$\mathit{A}\mathit{B}\mathit{C}\mathit{D}$` there's an added kern only after D (with a single character in the argument of `\mathit` TeX doesn't build a subformula, which it does with multiple characters).

Comment: I got it, thanks for that clear explanation!

Comment: And there is the same difference with `\mathrm` and `\textrm`: `$\mathrm{AV}\mathrm{AD}$.` and `$\textrm{AV}\textrm{AD}$.` have a different output, but the difference is way subtler that I would expect (you have to zoom in to notice that the distance between A and V in the `\textrm` formula in less large than that in the `\mathrm` formula, while I would expect the distance in the `\textrm` formula to be the same as in `AVAD.` in text mode).

Comment: The `V` has a non zero italic correction. So in `\mathrm{AV}\mathrm{AD}` there is a kern after V, which is not added for `\textrm{AV}\textrm{AD}` in math mode.

Comment: Yes, but why `$\textrm{AV}\textrm{AD}$.` doesn't display like `AVAD.` (in text mode)? That is with a negative kern.

Comment: @Maggyero `$\textrm{AV}\textrm{AD}$` makes two subformulas, which end up in two different `\hbox`es. No kern is thus applied.

Comment: In that case why a negative kern is applied in `$\textit{Af}\textit{fD}$`? (The two f are very close.)

Comment: @Maggyero No kern is applied. The first `f` is close to the second one because it extends past its nominal bounding box.

Comment: Okay thanks, that was not easy to get (since I don't know how to show TeX boxes).

Answer (score 11):

As egreg explained, the space between the letters is a design decision. In most cases I'd stick with TeX's default spacing, but it's possible to remove the italic correction. The result is shown in the second line of the following image.

[image: output with and without italic correction]

As you can see, the result is not always desirable: for the combination `PW`, the letters are much too close to each other. But for `WA` and `Tf`, the output looks better with the italic correction removed. Here's my implementation of `\ric` (**r**emove **i**talic **c**orrection):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\ric[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{#1_{}\kern-\scriptspace}}
\begin{document}
$PS\ TN\ CD\ WA\ Tf\ PW$

$\ric{P}S\ \ric{T}N\ \ric{C}D\ \ric{W}A\ \ric{T}f\ \ric{P}W$
\end{document}
```

A short explanation of the code: the italic correction is not used when the character is followed by a subscript, but no superscript. However, a `\scriptspace` is automatically added to the width of the subscript. I used an empty subscript and a negative kern to compensate the `\scriptspace`. The rest of the code takes care of the unwanted additional depth caused by the empty subscript.

Comment: can anyone tell me what's wrong with the `newtx` fonts -- more complete and consistent than `mathptmx`, based on `txfonts` but with corrected metrics, and work with tex itself, unlike `xits` and the other unicode maths fonts.  (living up to my moniker...)

Comment: _I_ can't tell you _anything_ about the `newtx` fonts, sorry.