# subscriptcorrection for mathdesign?

Tags: fonts, subscripts, mathdesign, mtpro

MathTime (mtpro2) contains a subscriptcorrection option, which is great.  Is there some way to get similar functionality for mathdesign?  In the MWE below the subscripts are too far from their `parent.'

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}         % pretty
%\usepackage[nosubscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}      % ugly
%\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}                 % ugly

\begin{document}
\(
 \omega_{jt}
\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is basically a feature request for the package author to deal with, IMO. It's far too broad for a question on this site, I think.

Comment: It's not about this specific font, just about fonts in general.  Perhaps it's a new package request, but I don't know that there's not a universal relatively simple way of dealing with it.

Comment: It being about *fonts in general* makes it even more broad than I originally thought. :-) Anyway, you might find parts of the solution at [Kerning super- and subscripts "semantically"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237647) interesting/useful.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  I am puzzled why this universal problem even exists.  The link doesn't quite explain that, or perhaps it does and I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not difficult to replicate the behavior of `subscriptcorrection` by fetching the code from `mtpro2.sty`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\_=\string"8000 \catcode`\_=12 }
\begingroup
 \catcode`\_=13
 \gdef_{\futurelet\next\s@@b}
\endgroup
\def\s@@b{\ifcat\relax\noexpand\next\expandafter\sb\else
 \expandafter\s@@b@\fi}
\def\s@@b@#1{\sb{\futurelet\next\sb@#1}}
\def\sb@{%
 \ifx\next\space@\def\next@. {\futurelet\next\sb@}\else
  \def\next@.{%
   \ifx\next f\mkern-\thr@@ mu\else
   \ifx\next j\mkern-\tw@ mu\else
   \ifx\next p\mkern-\tw@ mu\else
   \ifx\next t\mkern\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next y\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next A\mkern-\tw@ mu\else
   \ifx\next B\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next D\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next H\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next I\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next K\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next L\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next M\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next P\mkern-\@ne mu\else
   \ifx\next X\mkern-\tw@ mu\else
   \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}%
 \fi
 \next@.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\(\omega_{jt}\) (enabled)

\catcode`\_=8
\(\omega_{jt}\) (disabled)
\end{document}
```

Now you just have to fix all the kernings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Enrico.  I'm going to try that some time this weekend.