# Adjusting spacing in mathdesign

Tags: spacing, characters, kerning, mathdesign, active-characters

I like mathdesign package, but spacing between some letters looks pretty awful, for example, look at the letter *A*:

[image]

I've found the solution here: [Make Characters Active via Macro in Math Mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299798/make-characters-active-via-macro-in-math-mode). So, with this code

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
    % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
    \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
    \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000}%
}
\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathActive{A}{\mkern+1.5mu\std{A}\mkern+1.5mu}
```

the spacing became much better:

[image]

But I still have some questions regarding this code:

1. Is there a way to keep original subscript/superscript spacing for this letter? It would be logical if superscript was a bit more to the left than subscript.
2. Since I wasn't sure about the answer to the previous question, I've decided to find the way how to define this spacing myself, and here is the answer: [Kerning super- and subscripts "semantically"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237647/kerning-super-and-subscripts-semantically?noredirect=1&lq=1). But sometimes I need to use this character as sub/superscript itself, and I want to be able to write this: `X_A`. Right now I can just add a pair of brackets in the definition: `\DeclareMathActive{A}{{\mkern+1.5mu\std{A}\mkern+1.5mu}}`. But `futurelet` won't work after that.
3. Is there any other drawback in making characters active in math mode?
4. Does exist any other way to adjust spacing for a character in math mode?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In math mode you can use `\mkern`. For instance, for a superscript which needs to be adjusted, you can use  `A^{\! n}$`  (`\!` is a negative kerning equal to `-3 mu` (mathematical unit equal ti 1/18 em), or, slightly more adjusted `A^{\mkern -5mu n}$`

Comment: @Bernard, yes, I know that. What I'm interested in is how can I get right adjustment automatically (by writing something in preamble).

Comment: I'm afraid this would imply writing a special macro for exponent. As I see it, only the letters $A$ and $L$ would be involved. Maybe it would be more of an editor macro  to automatically add a negative kerning under conditions?

Comment: @Bernard, writing a macro is not a problem for me -- and by the way, in the second link there is a code (I don't understand what relation does it have to letters A and L). That's just not my question.