# Kerning and ligatures in upright math font with unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, context, unicode-math, ligatures, kerning

How can I get the kerning and ligatures of *text mode* in an *upright math font* with the **`unicode-math` package loaded**?

## 1. Without `unicode-math`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  affinity\par
  $\mathrm{affinity}$\par
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Kerning and ligatures of *text mode*.

## 2. With `unicode-math`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
  affinity\par
  $\mathrm{affinity}$\par
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Kerning and ligatures of *math mode*. I would like those of *text mode* here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of math alphabet commands in unicode-math is somewhat broken there are [open issues at github](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/254) which mentions `\mathit` but `\mathrm` is the same.

You can redefine `\mathrm` to use the Roman text font as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
  affinity\par
  $\mathrm{affinity}$\par
\end{document}
```

---

not working version including mathit

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Latin Modern Roman}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{lmroman12-italic}% affects normal math as well.
\DeclareMathAlphabet\xxmathit{EU2}{lmr}{m}{it}% EU1 for xetex EU2 for luatex
\def\xmathit#1{\xxmathit{\mathup{#1}}}% right font but ff ligature broken
\begin{document}
\showoutput
  1 affinity\par
  2 \textit{affinity}\par
  3 $affinity$\par
  4 $\mathrm{affinity}$\par
  5 $\xmathit{affinity}$\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now if I want to do the same thing but with `\mathit`, what is the *name* of the Latin Modern italic text font? (`Latin Modern Roman Italic` or `Latin Modern Roman-Italic` don't work.)

Comment: @Maggyero I'm not sure, I added an example to the question with two possible ways one commented out, the other selects the right font but ligatures not working. As I say I opened a github issue last year on mathit not working with unicode-math, you could ping will there.....

Comment: Is there a way to contact him directly on Stackexchange?

Comment: no, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/is-there-a-way-to-message-a-user-on-this-site, although he regularly passes by http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson (I could mail him:-)

Comment: Alright, yes could you email him? By the way, I read the Github issue you opened but at the end of the thread Will says: "(Discussion continued on LaTeX-L.)" without any url, what it this LaTeX-L?

Comment: @Maggyero latex-l the main discussion list for latex development (not a help list) http://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A0=latex-l

Comment: Thank you. I've just posted a related question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246552/mathematics-standards-for-typesetting-objects-other-than-variables?noredirect=1#comment586385_246552) and I would like very much to have your opinion on this matter since you are one of the most competent on this forum (nobody has really answered yet).

Comment: I've just realized that in classic TeX `\mathnormal`, `\mathit` and `\textit` should result in *3* different fonts being used, for instance *Cambria Math*, *Cambria* and *Palatino* respectively. That concept of 2 fonts for *math mode* (one math font, and one text font that may differ from the text font for *text mode*) was a little hard to understand. Now about the `unicode-math` package, what do you think of my suggestion below?

Answer (score 1):

To follow-up the discussion in the comments of David Carlisle's answer about the `unicode-math` package:

In LaTeX, there are two fonts in math mode:

- one for **letters** (variables), usually called *math font* (better called *math letter font*);
- one for **words**, usually called *math text font* (better called *math word font*),

and one text font in text mode, usually called *text font*.

**The *text font* and the *math text font* may be different:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{ppl} % sets Palatino as text font
\begin{document}
    $\mathnormal{affinity}$\par    % math letter font
    $\mathit{affinity}$\par        % math word font
    $\textit{affinity}$\par        % text font
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `\mathnormal`, `\mathit` and `\textit` result in three different fonts being used: Latin Modern Math, Latin Modern and Palatino respectively.

With the `unicode-math` package loaded, the output becomes different:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Palatino}             % sets Palatino as text font
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}    % sets Latin Modern Math as math letter font
\begin{document}
    $\mathnormal{affinity}$\par    % math letter font
    $\mathit{affinity}$\par        % math word font
    $\textit{affinity}$\par        % text font
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here the package redefines `\mathnormal` as nothing and `\mathit` as *math letter font* (instead of *math word font* in classic LaTeX). So by default the `unicode-math` package breaks the standard behaviour of LaTeX. That is why David Carlisle opened an [issue](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/254) at Github as said in his answer (there is another interesting Github issue about the same problem [here](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/175)).

**As suggested by David Carlisle in the Github issue, I first thought about introducing new math font commands `\mathwxx` for math *word* font in the `unicode-math` package, to keep backward compatibility:**

[image]

But finally I am wondering if those new math font commands `\mathwxx` are needed, and even if they make sense: indeed, when do we need to use an *upright* math *letter* font after all? Math letter fonts are only for variables, therefore they should always be in *italic*, never *upright*. We only need an upright math font for non variables, that is for math *word* fonts, so we should better replace the math *letter* font of the Unicode ranges `\mathup` and `\mathbf` by a math *word* font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Palatino}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Latin Modern Roman} % sets a math word font instead of the default math letter font
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{lmroman12-bold}   % sets a math word font instead of the default math letter font
\let\mathnormal\mathit                          % redefines \mathnormal as before the unicode-math package
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \texttt{\backslash mathup}: $\mathup{affinity}$\\
    \texttt{\backslash mathbf}: $\mathbf{affinity}$\\
    \texttt{\backslash mathit} or \texttt{\backslash mathnormal}: $\mathit{affinity}$ (default)\\
    \texttt{\backslash mathbfit}: $\mathbfit{affinity}$\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus with that setup we get the standard LaTeX behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure the above is really an answer, more an extended comment. But some comments. It is best not to use `minimal` class for font examples as there are many artefacts due to the fact that it doesn't set up fonts. "two fonts in math mode" isn't right in classic tex (where there are usually four, and up to 16) or unicode-math (where there is usually just one).

Comment: Your initial example is using computer modern not latin modern for math, the missing `mathnormal` commands are not because `\mathnormal` is defined to do nothing but as warned in the log `Missing character: There is no  (U+1D44E) in font cmmi10!` the final example says that with that suggested setup you get "the default latex behaviour" but it shows exactly the problem that is raised in github that `\mathit` is giving the math italic font as accessed by `\mathnormal` (or no font command at all) instead of a text italic font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, this was to continue our discussion with some visual examples. 1. 'It is best not to use `minimal`', alright, I'll edit the answer. 2. 'There are usually four, and up to sixteen', you're right, actually I meant two fonts in the generic sense: the math font used for variables (math letter *italic*) and the math font used for constants, operators and subscript specifiers (math word *upright*). 3. 'Your initial example is using computer modern, not latin modern for math', that's just what I wanted to ask you: how to use *Latin modern math* without the `unicode-math` package?

Comment: The site quidelines discourage discourage discousion posted via (non-)answers. For latin modern math then you need something equivalent to unicode-math as it has not been split up and encoded to match the classic math encodings as far as I know.  I still don't agree that "two fonts" has any reasonable interpretation here, or that variables are always set italic or in the same font: for variables in classic encodings, single letter latin alphabet is set with math italic, multi-letter latin alphabet is set with \mathit, single letter uppercase Greek is usually set upright (same font as \mathrm).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: 4. 'The missing mathnormal commands are not because `\mathnormal` is defined to do nothing', alright, thanks. 5. 'It shows exactly the problem that is raised in github', yes, but I have a question: are there really people that use the standard `\mathit` for writing math words (multi-letter text)? If yes, to not break backward compatibility my suggestion to introduce a new math command `\mathwxx` for math *words* should be the opposite: introducing a new math command `\mathlxx` for math *letters* and keeping the `\mathxx` command for math *words* (default LaTeX behaviour).

Comment: Yes of course people use `\mathit` to make multi-letter words, what other use would it have? See for example this answer of egreg's giving `\mathit` as the solution to make a variable called AB as opposed to the product of two variables A and B http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16433/math-letters-italic-correction/16442#16442 but search the internet for `\mathit` you will find it is almost always used with more than one letter in its argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for this great example of use of `\mathit`. I had a discussion with egreg in his answer at the link you provided, so now I truly understand the difference with `\textit`. And the same example applies to `\mathrm` and `\textrm`, even if it's a bit harder to notice. So I removed my bad conclusion about the changes to be made in the `unicode-math` package in this thread and now *really* want to convince Will Robertson and Khaled Hosny to implement the correction you suggested to their package. Do they plan to do it soon or they don't agree with you?

Comment: I agree with the comments, it's just a matter of resources (i.e., time). I'd hoped to address this many months ago by now… apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @WillRobertson: Fantastic, thank you very much! There's exactly the same problem with ConTeXt since it uses Unicode math as well. I'll try again to talk about it to Hans Hagen. Could you just give me a short overview of the solution to the problem so that I can convince him (I'm just an average TeX user)? I've already pointed out to him the bug in the ConTeXt mailing list a few weeks ago but I was not very convincing: see [here](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/082218.html).