# Ligatures are not used in OpenType maths families?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, unicode-math

The appended plain TeX example shows three cases:

- maths alphabets `\rm`, `\bf`, `\it` using plain TeX setup
- similarly maths alphabets loaded from "classical" Latin Modern fonts
- similarly maths alphabets loaded with OpenType Latin Modern fonts

For the first two cases, text is set using ligatures; e.g., `{\fam\itfam fin}` will produce a ligature. In the final case when an OpenType font is used, the ligature doesn't appear. Using the font in-text shows that ligatures are being selected otherwise.

So what's going on? [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245389/179) spotted this happening trying to fix up the behaviour of `unicode-math`, and I've been trying to figure out whether this is my fault! The same happens for both XeTeX and LuaTeX+luaotfload, so if it's an oversight, they are both culpable.

[image: example of ligatures not working]

```
%!TEX TS-program = XeTeX

\ifx\XeTeXversion\undefined
  \input luaotfload.sty
  \def\otf#1{file:#1.otf}
\else
  \def\otf#1{[#1.otf]}
\fi

\hsize=10cm
\parindent=0pt\relax

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hrule
\bigskip

{\bf Default \TeX}

Roman, italic, and bold math families:
$$ {\fam0 abcfin} \quad {\fam\itfam } \quad {\fam\bffam abcfin} $$

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\font\myrm = ec-lmr10 at 10pt\relax
\font\mybf = ec-lmbx10 at 10pt\relax
\font\myit = ec-lmri10 at 10pt\relax

\newfam\rmmathfam
\newfam\bfmathfam
\newfam\itmathfam

\textfont\rmmathfam\myrm
\textfont\bfmathfam\mybf
\textfont\itmathfam\myit

\hrule
\bigskip

{\bf Loading new tfm fonts}

Roman ({\myrm abcfin}), italic ({\myit abcfin}), and bold ({\mybf abcfin}) families:
$$ {\fam\rmmathfam abcfin} \quad {\fam\itmathfam abcfin} \quad {\fam\bfmathfam abcfin} $$


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\font\Urm = "\otf{lmroman10-regular}" at 10pt\relax
\font\Ubf = "\otf{lmroman10-bold}" at 10pt\relax
\font\Uit = "\otf{lmroman10-italic}" at 10pt\relax

\newfam\Urmmathfam
\newfam\Ubfmathfam
\newfam\Uitmathfam

\textfont\Urmmathfam\Urm
\textfont\Ubfmathfam\Ubf
\textfont\Uitmathfam\Uit

\hrule
\bigskip

{\bf Loading new OpenType fonts}

Roman ({\Urm abcfin}), italic ({\Uit abcfin}), and bold ({\Ubf abcfin}) families:
$$ {\fam\Urmmathfam abcfin} \quad {\fam\Uitmathfam abcfin} \quad {\fam\Ubfmathfam abcfin} $$

\bye
```

Comment: maybe `luaotfload` doesn't  do  text shaping in math nodes?

Comment: I should have mentioned: same for XeTeX.

Comment: Did anything came out here? Here the problem came up again http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277362/lualatex-no-kerning-within-operatorname-when-not-loading-lmodern-package, and as far as I can see it is not the fault of fontspec (I get it with luaotfload alone too), and it happens in xetex too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer — I don't think so, sorry; `unicode-math` applies the `base` mode (search for `Renderer=Basic` in the source if you're interested) … and I'm not sure where to go next

Comment: @WillRobertson: What do you mean with base mode in unicode-math? The fonts used by \mathrm or \operatorname don't seem to use it, I had to force it as you can see in my answer to the new question. In context the kerning is missing too and I tried to discuss it on the context list but all I could extract from Hans is "that node mode in math is different" and that in context there is an option to put operators names in a box so that text kerning can kick in.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer — Apologies, I went off on the wrong tangent. V busy right now. I think in the long run we might need to adopt a method similar to ConTeXt's…

Comment: @WillRobertson: A box for operatornames would probably work, but for \mathrm I have doubt: People are lazy and so do have the habit to put things in \mathrm which works only in math, e.g. `\mathrm{a\neq b}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer — very true; I guess we'll need some pretty extreme effort to getting things working properly then :(

Comment: Well I realized that with unicode-math putting math in `\mathrm` is a dangerous habit anyway: If the range is mapped to some text font they are lost. Also loading the font in mode base works, and with unicode math there is a quite natural interface. See my edit http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277395/2388. So perhaps one only need some interface for the fontspec solution.

Answer (score 13):

For luatex you can load the fonts in base mode

[image]

```
\ifx\XeTeXversion\undefined
  \input luaotfload.sty
  \def\otf#1{file:#1.otf:mode=base}
\else
  \def\otf#1{[#1.otf]}
\fi
```

For xetex, I pinged Arthur in chat....

`luaotfload` documentation explains the need for this:

> `base` mode works by mapping OpenType
>     features to traditional TeX ligature and kerning mechanisms.
>
> Supporting only non-contextual substitutions and kerning
>     pairs, it is the slightly faster, albeit somewhat limited, variant.
>
> `node` mode works by processing TeX’s internal
>     node list directly at the lua end and supports
>     a wider range of OpenType features.
>
> The downside is that the intricate operations required for
>     `node` mode may slow down typesetting especially
>     with complex fonts and it does not work in math mode.
>
> By default `luaotfload` is in `node`
>     mode, and `base` mode has to be requested where needed,
>     e.g. for math fonts.