# pdfTex: \operatorname with Computer Modern Roman

Tags: fonts, amsmath, math-operators

I am using the default font, Computer Modern Roman, and I am trying to get `\operatorname` to work properly. The issue is that it appears to look identical to normal text. This question: [LuaLaTeX: No kerning within \operatorname when not loading lmodern package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277362/lualatex-no-kerning-within-operatorname-when-not-loading-lmodern-package/277364) shows a method for resolving this in LuaTex.

How can I achieve this in pdfTex?

**Example**

```
\documentclass{report}

% Math packages
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    $foo$ foo $\operatorname{foo}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above image the last two words should not look the same.

If you switch the default font, for example: `\renewcommand*\rmdefault{bch}`. You will get the following result:

[image]

I don't want to change the default font, I just want to make `\operatorname` show a distinction.

Comment: Welcome! This is normal. The reason the font change makes a difference is because it changes the default text font but not the default maths fonts so the maths fonts are still Computer Modern and now the default serif is different. Generally speaking, you want your maths fonts to cohere with your text fonts: the above mix would not look good which is why you would rarely simply change the default serif.

Comment: Note that the point in the question you linked is precisely that the results *differ* in maths mode - not that they are the same. And the problem there doesn't apply to pdfTeX - that's the point, too. It just works with TeX/pdfTeX. You don't have to do anything to get the kerning to be effective.

Comment: @cfr, I understand that you should stick with a font family. I don't want to change the font of my math, but I do want `\operatorname` to be typeset differently. This is for use in my thesis which has a lot of math and I need a clear distinction between text, symbols, and function names (among other things). In this context, `\operatorname` would be used to describe a function name, similar to how `\sin` is used to describe the sine function.

Comment: One can change the font used by \operatorname, but this would affect also numbers, parentheses and other math symbols.

Comment: How about `\operatorname{\text{foo}}`?

Comment: It is using the same font as `\sin` already, isn't it?

Comment: @HenriMenke - that shows no visible difference. @cfr - Yes, `\sin` is the same as `\operatorname{sin}`, which looks the same as `sin`, in this font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amsmath macro `\operatorname` is designed to use the same font as the one used by `\DeclareMathOperator`.

It is a fact of life that this font is hardcoded in both LaTeX and AMSmath source code (more precisely fontmath.ltx or amsopn.sty) to use the so-named 'operators' math font. This happens via

```
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symoperators}
```

You can customize `\operator@font` (package `mathastext` does it). But as you see you should refer to one the (16 in PDFTeX) math font family (`\mathgroup` in LaTeX, `\fam` in TeX). Besides you will thus affect all commands user-defined via `\DeclareMathOperator` or those pre-defined like `\sin`, `\cos` which use a more direct approach but still have `\operator@font` hardcoded therein.

Comment: This gave me just enough to come up with a working solution. I redefined `\operator@font` using a pre-existing math group, as suggested. For those of you interested, I placed the following after loading all of my packages: `\makeatletter \def\operator@font{\mathrm}  \makeatother`. You'll notice that it is similar to `\mathnormal`, but just different enough.

Comment: @TehTechGuy This seems to affect only the first letter of an oeprator like deg, giving ugly results.