# How to use OpenType Latin Modern Roman in \mathrm?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex

Running the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test $\mathrm{VARfi}$
\end{document}
```

using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I observed that `Test` was rendered in OpenType Latin Modern Roman while `VAR` was rendered in TFM-based Computer Modern Roman. Is it possible to change `\mathrm` to use OpenType Latin Modern Roman?

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Hmm… No. I’ll admit that this is a trick question: The kerning between `V` and `A` and the `fi` ligature will both disappear, and therefore the result is not the full OpenType Latin Modern Roman.

Comment: Welcome back cfr! I didn't see you around for a while or am I wrong?

Comment: @RuixiZhang - In addition to loading the `fontspec` package, one also needs to execute `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` to get your desired outcome, *viz.*, kerning between V and A and the `fi` ligature.

Comment: @RuixiZhang if you want ligatures you need to force base mode with luatex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277395/2388

Comment: @RuixiZhang Well, it depends what you mean by 'full'. I guess you mean 'with the kerning and ligature features of traditional maths fonts', but that should be in your question. Probably the question is a duplicate of one of the earlier ones in that case, though there doesn't seem to be a solution for XeLaTeX (?).

Comment: @cfr Let's agree to disagree. If I asked “how to use OpenType XXX in LaTeX?”, I (implicitly) expect my professional fonts can be used with LaTeX out of the box, or that their features can be accessed without too much work, or a answer that simply says “no, but some packages are working on it”. On another note, there seems to be no solutions for XeTeX for over four years `:(`.

Comment: @Mico Math font families `$\mathrm{VARfi}$` need more works and XeTeX refuses to kern or to join letters into ligatures as far as I know.

Comment: @RuixiZhang - Indeed: I tested out my earlier claim with LuaLaTeX, not XeLaTeX. I wasn't aware until now of XeLaTeX's limitations in this respect.

Comment: It is just than now the question seems to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252493/ligatures-are-not-used-in-opentype-maths-families, even though that isn't obvious from the question. @RuixiZhang