# Why is there a different kern between delimiters and math characters compared to their italic text character?

Tags: delimiters, kerning

Occasionally, I like to typeset lists using the `$\left< ... \right>$` notation in order to account for larger contents. I noticed that there is a difference in kerning toward the closing delimiter, depending on whether the list contains mathematical items or a word in italics font. Broken down to a MWE, it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    $\left<\textit{element}\right>$\\   
    $\left< r,s,t \right>$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The kern between the *t* and `>` is much smaller in the text line than in the math line.

My questions are: Which factors contribute to this behaviour? Can I control the kerning in the first row so that it is exactly the same as in the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply an italic correction `\/` to the text:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    $\left<\textit{element\/}\right>$\\   
    $\left< r,s,t \right>$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOR MORE INFORMATION:**

The *comments* following this answer, [Math letter's italic correction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16433/math-letters-italic-correction/16442#16442), discuss some aspects of the italic correction in math mode.

Comment: I thought the italic correction was automatically inserted by `\textit`, in contrast to `\itshape`?

Comment: @FelixEmanuel I am not an expert on the italic correction.  But if I learn more, I will elaborate.

Comment: @FelixEmanuel I am going to take a guess and say that because there is no "text" (only math) following the `\textit`, the italic correction is not applied.  For example, the italic correction **IS** applied if you were to input it as follows: `\textrm{\textit{element}}`.  Here the exit from italic mode leaves you in text mode.

Comment: @FelixEmanuel I found this comment by egreg: "In math mode TeX applies automatically the italic correction in well determined situations. The addition is done only at the end of the subformula, so with $\mathit{A}\mathit{B}\mathit{C}\mathit{D}$ there's an added kern only after D (with a single character in the argument of \mathit TeX doesn't build a subformula, which it does with multiple characters)" to the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16433/math-letters-italic-correction/16442#16442

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I still see some very minor difference in, say `$\left< x\right>$` and `$\left< \textit{x\/}\right>$`, these are probably to be explained by the different kerning for `x` in math and text fonts, right?

Comment: @FelixEmanuel You are welcome.  I would guess you are right, but would note that with computer modern as the font, they typeset identically.