# Typeset equation with multiple aligned conditions on the right

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
DS &= \frac{100}{l} * \sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t &&  d_t &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
1, & sonst\end{array}\right.\\
WDS &=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t|y_t-\hat{y}_t|}{\sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t'|y_t-\hat{y}_t|} && d_t &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
1, & sonst\end{array}\right. &&\\
d_t' &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
0, & sonst\end{array}\right.\\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want an output including 2 equations: In the first row DS, with the condition *d<sub>t</sub>*, and in the second row WDS with *d<sub>t</sub>* and *d'<sub>t</sub>* (*d<sub>t</sub>* and *d'<sub>t</sub>* aligned)

This picture shows the output of the code:

[image: This is the actual output of the latex code]

The desired form of the output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. I hope the picture I added in the edit explains my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\text{DS} &= \frac{100}{l} \cdot \sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t &  d_t &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
1, & \text{sonst}\end{array}\right.\\
\text{WDS} &=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t|y_t-\hat{y}_t|}{\sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t'|y_t-\hat{y}_t|} & d_t &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
1, & \text{sonst}\end{array}\right. &&\\
&&d_t' &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
0, & \text{sonst}\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

I also changed your  `*` to `\cdot`, because I think t looks nicer. And more importantly I wrapped `DS` , `WDS`, and `sonst` into `\text{ }`. If you don't do this, LaTeX will think you're typeseting `s*o*n*s*t` which will make the spacing between letters weird (you can see that by typesetting `\emph{beispiffel} $beispiffel$`)

[image]

Comment: Yes- I only  added `\nonumber` to the third equation. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also consider the suggestion to use the `cases` environment, by @JouleV

Comment: I'm not sure why you have put two `&&` before the `d_t` elements.  That leaves an overly large space after the second equals sign.

Comment: That is correct, I agree. I just copied that part from OPs MWE. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? Just add some more `&`s to `align`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ds}{DS}
\DeclareMathOperator{\wds}{WDS}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\ds &= \frac{100}{l}\cdot\sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t &&&  d_t &= 
\begin{cases}
0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
1, & \text{sonst}
\end{cases}\\
\wds &=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t|y_t-\hat{y}_t|}{\sum_{t=1}^{l}d_t'|y_t-\hat{y}_t|} &&& d_t &= 
\begin{cases}
0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
1, & \text{sonst}
\end{cases} &&\\
&&&&d_t' &= 
\begin{cases} 
0, & (\hat{y}_t - \hat{y}_{t-1})(y_t - y_{t-1}) \\
0, & \text{sonst}
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- I use `\cdot` as a substitution of `*`.
- I use `cases` instead of `array`.
- I use `\text{sonst}` instead of `sonst` (which is understood as *s* × *o* × *n* × *s* × *t*).
- I use `\DeclareMathOperator` for `\ds` and `\wds`, thanks to [@sheß](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33758/she%C3%9F) for pointing that out!

Comment: I'd also use `\text{..}` for DS and WDS... the kerning for WDS looks especially weird. I wonder what could be done to make people use `\text{..}` more consistently in formulas.

Comment: @sheß Thanks to pointing out that. But I don't think DS and WDS need `\text`, they need `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: Why? What's the difference? I tried to look it up here and aside from the fact that `\DeclareMathOperator` is -- by name -- intended for operators and not variables. I don't see what the differences is.

Comment: @sheß IMHO `\text` is not for things like this. The reason I use `\DeclareMathOperator` is that this command is for things like `\sin`, `\cos`, etc., and I think "DS" and "WDS" are similar.

Comment: Mh, interesting, I didn't find much on this, except the unsatisfactory (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/two-letter-variable-names) and a few very localized mainly opinion-based questions. So I created this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482743/typesetting-multi-letter-varaible-names-in-math-declaremathoperator-or-text

Comment: @sheß and I just upvoted it.