# How do I type an expression with decimal in math-mode?

Tags: math-mode, typography

I want

> slope = 0.0021

How do I do this in math-mode?

Comment: Welcome! Use `\text`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\text{slope} = 0.0021$ or
\[\text{slope} = 0.0021\]
\end{document}`

Comment: Please clarify the nature of your query. E.g., are you familiar with TeX's (and LaTeX's) two types of math mode: *inline* math mode and *display* math mode? Do you know how to enter and exit inline math mode and display math mode? Alternatively, are you asking about how to typeset the word "slope" in upright lettering while in (inline or display) math mode? Please advise.

Comment: Welcome! To write decimal numbers you don't need nothing special: just use a dot (.) and put numbers between it.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it is better to use `\mathrm{slope}` or `\mathit{slope}`. The style of `\text` changes depending on the outside font and this is normally not what you want for a variable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not sure I agree. In many situations one does want to adjust the font to the ambient font, e.g. in a theorem.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat intermediary text like "while" or "larger than" yes, but not variables. Longer "text variables" should like short variables  `x` or `y` have a uniform look. See e.g. daleif's comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482743/typesetting-multi-letter-variable-names-in-math-mode

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I beg to disagree. It really depends on the case, but IMHO slope is not a variable but a term. Let’s say we were talking about, say, “rotation angle “ instead of “slope”. Would you then agree that \text is to be used?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat not if it is used in a equation like in the example above. Then is doesn't matter if the text is "angle" or "duck rotation vector".  It is then a math object and for math objects the look matters and they shouldn't change it (with the exception of math e.g. in heading which can get overall bolder).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems like we have a disagreement, then. Math operators do not change their font, terms do. Basically all math and physics books I know would adjust the font.