# Making Verbatim and Beamer play nice

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I'm writing a beamer presentation on basic math type-setting in latex and I've been trying to use verbatim to display how math equations are typed. Using `fragile` this works, but I still get several annoying error messages every time I compile, so I'm never sure if I have an actual error or if beamer is just complaining about verbatim. The current offender would be:

```
\begin{verbatim}
\[
  X := \bigcup_{n \in \Mb N}\coprod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} 
       (X_\lambda \cap Y_\lambda ) \vee \Mb S^{n}.
\]
\end{verbatim}
```

I get error messages along the lines of:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 11.

[1{/home/schlatjj/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./Math.toc)
[2] (./Math.vrb

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 6.

) [3] (./Math.vrb) [4] (./Math.vrb
! Undefined control sequence.
\test@single@character ...ken ->\def \math@format 
                                                  ##1{\mydollar ##1\mydollar...
l.10   \end{verbatim}
```

Are there any workarounds for this, something I can change in the code to make these error messages go away?

Comment: It seems that you use [this hack](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/bad-spacing-of-math-letters-within-italic-text/4939#4939) of mine. (I told you that I wouldn't suggest using it ...) Does removing the hack make things work?

Comment: Yes, it does. I removed it and it fixed the issue. It seemed like such an impressive hack at the time. Too bad I can't mark your comment as the answer, although since there wasn't really an issue to begin with. It might be appropriate to delete the question.

Comment: If you regard it helpful, I can make my comment an answer. You can also upvote the comment. Moreover, it might help to use `\protect` at some appropriate places; for this you'd better post a minimal working example.

Comment: @Hendrik: your comment would be fine as answer! Jacob could simply uncheck my answer (which rather deals with the warning) and then mark your answer as accepted. Would be perfectly fine.

Comment: That would be fine with me.

Comment: @Jacob: Can you please add a minimal example that exhibits the error? (Don't include my hack as it's too long; just _indicate_ where you include it.)

Comment: Related: [Why does `! Missing $ inserted.` occur when using \verb in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197234/5645)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use [this hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/bad-spacing-of-math-letters-within-italic-text/4939#4939) of mine. (I told you that I wouldn't suggest using it, but I feel honored that you like it ...) However, as I wrote there, the hack is designed for the CM fonts only, so you shouldn't use it with the standard `beamer` fonts.

That said, I can't reproduce the error. I used the code Stefan Kottwitz had in the [first version of his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/7064/revisions), and added my hack in the preamble. This compiles nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: since the `fragile` option is obviously known by the OP, I removed that option suggestion.

At least regarding the warnings: the one oncerning the missing size 4 in cmss can be removed simply by

```
\let\Tiny\tiny
```

If you don't need size 4 and thus `\Tiny`, this could be sufficient.

Comment: The OP knows about `fragile`; forgot to mark this as code ...

Comment: I am using fragile. It turns out it was an issue with some stray code I had in my macro package.

Comment: @Hendrik, @Jacob: ah, I understand. I just did not see `fragile` when it wasn't marked as code. I edited my entry. I don't delete, perhaps somebody benefits from the tiny `\Tiny` workaround.