# Why does `! Missing $ inserted.` occur when using \verb in beamer?

Tags: beamer, errors, verbatim

When I use `\verb+...+` within `beamer` I get

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 \end{frame}

?
```

What is going wrong and how do I fix this problem?

A minimal example is

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Some text \verb+\int+
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note to moderators: This question should be a reference question. Can somebody please make it community wiki?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: You've answered another beamer/fragile question. Could you please extend my community wiki answer with an explanation how fragile works?

Comment: (related: [errors - How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block/640353#comment48026_24574))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix the problem by adding `fragile`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
        Some text \verb+\int+
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's worth expanding the answer with how `fragile` works maybe? :-) *or a link

Comment: @1010011010 I don't know how it works. If you know it, please feel free to add it to the answer. That is one reason why I made my answer "Community wiki".

Comment: Regarding how fragile works, one possible implementation is to collect the environment content verbatim then `scantokens` it when needed. (To check if it's correct, consult beamer source code.)