# ellipsis in German quotation marks

Tags: spacing, german, ellipsis

What's the right way to typeset an ellipsis in German quotation marks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{mathic=true} %%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3496/
\begin{document}
Terme schreiben wir in Anführungszeichen "`\dots"'. %or "`\ldots"'
\end{document}
```

produces, when compiled with `pdflatex`,

> Terme schreiben wir in Anführungszeichen „… “.

What's the canonical way to get rid of the space between … and “? Surely, we can write something like

```
\kern.1em\textellipsis\kern-.12em
```

, but the kerning amounts would be guessed and might not be portable when you change font families.

Comment: ```"`\dots\unkern"'``` might be worth a try, but what exactly 'looks right' is a matter of taste.

Comment: How is the mathtools stuff relevant to this question? `mathic` only applies to `\(...\)`

Comment: `\dots` and friends are defined via `amsmath`, which is loaded by `mathtools`.

Comment: `mathtools` does not change any dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to cancel out the kerning after the ellipsis with `\unkern`. I got the idea from browsing the [`csquotes` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) to see how `csquotes` handles its ellipsis.

```
Terme schreiben wir in Anführungszeichen "`\dots\unkern"'.
```

[image: Terme schreiben wir in Anführungszeichen "`\dots\unkern"'.]

The spacing seems less excessive now, but one might still feel the need for a little manual extra correction. What exactly looks right is to a certain degree a matter of taste.

It might be worth a try to use centred dots or one centred placeholder symbol instead of dots on the baseline. That way the apparent asymmetry with the closing upper quotation mark could be alleviated. Alternatively you could just fill in a dummy term.