# Wedge product symbol (exterior/alternating product)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/wedge-power-symbol) question has a similar title, but my question is different.

I would like to denote the kth exterior power similar to this:

[image]

`\wedge` is too small and `\bigwedge` is not only too big but also centered in a strange way:

[image]

Also, I don't like using `\Lambda` instead. I tried the `relsize` package, which provides the command `\mathlarger{}`. This is the result:

[image: 3]

As you see, the wedge is still too small and there is too much space between the wedge and the letter k.

Do you know a good solution?

Comment: dAdd a negative kerning to the  exponent – something like `\bigwedge^{\mkern-6mu k}` (value to be adjusted to the real spacing).

Comment: BTW, if any of the answers helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept one of them by clicking on the checkmark symbol.

Comment: @chsk The problem is that I found several answers helpful.

Comment: @Filippo Ah, there's an easy solution to that. Just accept *mine* then. ;)

Comment: @chsk I know that was a joke, but I don't see the point in accepting one specific answer and therefore making it seem more helpful than the others. I think that all answers can be helpful to someone reading this question, especially because different methods have been used to solve the problem.

Comment: @Filippo that's true, but accepting an answer will also give whoever posted it a reputation boost. Think of it as giving whoever you think is most deserving of it a little "thanks" for taking time out of their day to help you. *All* answers will remain visible anyway, so whoever looks at this in the future will see everything that people offered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention that a regular upper-case `\Lambda` won't cut it, but you could use a sans-serif one. I took the liberty of adapting @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537350/158639) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537208/upright-sans-serif-math-capital-greek-using-luaxelatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setmathfontface\mathsans{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newcommand{\wedgeprod}{\mathsans{\mupLambda}}
\begin{document}
$$\wedgeprod^k V = {} \underbrace{ V \wedge V \dots \wedge V }_{\text{$k$ times}}$$
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Definitely far from perfect, but better than nothing.

Comment: There is a little v to the RHS :-) +1

Comment: D'oh. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I vote your efforts and .....of the users :-)

Comment: Fixed & much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a scaled down and raised up `\bigwedge` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\exterior}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette\exterior@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\exterior@}[2]{%
  % raise to the baseline
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
  % select the script size relative to the current font
  \fontsize{\sf@size}{0}%
  % nullify the math surround
  \m@th
  % typeset \bigwedge, but using \textstyle in displays
  $\ifx#1\displaystyle\textstyle\else#1\fi\bigwedge$}%
  % the exponent, a bit nearer to the symbol
  ^{\mspace{-2mu}#2}%
  % remove the \scriptspace
  \kern-\scriptspace
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\exterior{k}V &= {\underbrace{V\wedge V\wedge\dots\wedge V}_{\text{$k$ times}}}
\\
\exterior{k}(V) &= {\underbrace{V\wedge V\wedge\dots\wedge V}_{\text{$k$ times}}}
\\
a&=V_{\exterior{k}V}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here I use a rotated text `V` to make the operator.  Based on the OP's figures, I employed sffamily.  Also, there appeared to be two sizes employed, so I mirrored that in `\lamop` and `\lamopbold`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,rotating}
\DeclareMathOperator\lamopbold{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\textsf{V}}}
\DeclareMathOperator\lamop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\footnotesize\textsf{V}}}
\begin{document}
\[
 \lamopbold^{\!k}(V) = \underbrace{V \lamop \dots \lamop V}_{\text{k times}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here I add my proposal using a newcommand `\bigw` (of the standard symbol of Amsmath, `\bigwedge`)  created with `\scalebox` contained in `graphicx` package.
You can decrease the symbol `\bigw` changing the parameter of `\scalebox{.95}[1]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\bigw{\scalebox{.95}[1]{$\bigwedge$}}
\begin{document}

\[\bigw^{\!k}(V)=\underbrace{V \wedge V \dotsb \wedge V }_{k \text{ times}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]