# Nicematrix version 6.26d not backward compatible?

Tags: nicematrix

I have installed Texlive on a new Windows and recognised, that I now receive an error from the nicematrix package.

This is the result with the version from Overleaf (using LuaLaTeX)
[image]

This is the result when using 6.26d of nicematrix.sty
[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools} % includes: \usepackage{amsmath} (-> needed e.g. for bmatrix) !! load BEFORE \usepackage{unicode-math}
%\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/bad-spacing-of-math-letters-within-italic-text
\usepackage{unicode-math}   %Unicode mathematics support for X?TEX and LuaTEX
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\mathbfit{W}_{x\star} = 
\begin{NiceArray}{[cccc]@{\quad\enspace}l}
w_{x\star\,{0,1}} & w_{x\star\,{0,2}} & \ldots & w_{x\star\,{0,h}} & \text{bias} \\ 
w_{x\star\,{1,1}} & w_{x\star\,{1,2}} & \ldots & w_{x\star\,{1,h}} & \Block{4-1}{d \text{ features}} \\
w_{x\star\,{2,1}} & w_{x\star\,{2,2}} & \ldots & w_{x\star\,{2,h}}\\
\vdots            & \vdots            & \ddots & \vdots      \\
w_{x\star\,{d,1}} & w_{x\star\,{d,2}} & \ldots & w_{x\star\,{d,h}}\\
\CodeAfter
\UnderBrace[shorten,yshift=0pt]{last-1}{last-4}{h\,\,\mathrm{hidden\: units}}
\SubMatrix{.}{1-4}{1-4}{\}}[xshift=2mm]
\SubMatrix{.}{2-4}{5-4}{\}}[xshift=2mm]
\end{NiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If I remove `[` and `]` in `\begin{NiceArray}{[cccc]@{\quad\enspace}l}`, the error is gone, but also the brackets of the matrix.

[image]

Comment: You are right. There is a problem. I will investigate (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). As a workaround, you can write `\left[` and `\right]` instead of `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uploaded on CTAN a new version (v. 6.27a 2024-02-19) which solves that bug.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot for the fast fix!