# Why \( and \) were not defined as robust commands in the first place?

Tags: math-mode, macros, latex-base

I am aware of the difference between using `\(...\)` and `$...$` (in moving arguments, for example), and yes, I've read the answers to this question: [Are \( and \) preferable to $?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to)). I also know the definition of `\(` and `\)`:

```
 \def\({\relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}
 \def\){\relax\ifmmode\ifinner$\else\@badmath\fi\else\@badmath\fi}
```

(taken from Section 55.2 of  [source2e.pdf](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf))

My question here is: couldn't `\(` and `\)` have been defined as robust commands in the LaTeX kernel? Is there any (non trivial) reason explaining why they were defined as fragile commands?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the `fixltx2e` package ends with

```
\MakeRobust\(
\MakeRobust\)
\MakeRobust\[
\MakeRobust\]
\MakeRobust\makebox
\MakeRobust\savebox
\MakeRobust\framebox
\MakeRobust\parbox
\MakeRobust\rule
\MakeRobust\raisebox
```

it is probably safe to say that it was simply a mistake that was left around because the kernel can't change at this point. It's also worth pointing out that this is covered in Section 4 in the `fixltx2e` documentation titled “Fixes added for 2005/12/01.”