# \listoffigures chokes on inline math delimiters in captions. What is going on?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, amsmath

I'm working on my thesis, and I've realized that, any time I try to use \( \)-type inline delimiters in captions, that pdflatex breaks. While I can weasel out of actually \needing\ math in my captions, it's very inconvenient. I'm pretty perplexed.

Here's a (relatively) minimal example that breaks for me:

```
\documentclass{uafthesis}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Graphics stuff

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{angle.png}
\caption{\(\theta \)}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Here's a sample of the output:

> ! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.1 ...k or  to continue without it.}}}{2}
>
> ? 
>   ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
>    ...r  to continue without it.}}
>
> l.1 ...k or  to continue without it.}}}{2}
>
> ?

Some things:

- `uafthesis` is the unofficial official document class for my university. It has been written mostly by physics grad students by hacking at other document classes. My fork is [here](https://github.com/jesusabdullah/uafthesis/).
- This only happens if I include `amsmath`.
- The minimal example and the resulting log file are gisted [here](https://gist.github.com/901127).

I'm defending tomorrow, and I have to turn in my thesis pretty soon, so hopefully we can figure this out within a day or so! If not, I understand, and thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I asked irc://freenode.com/#latex, and they said to use the `fixltx2e` package, or alternately, to use dollar signs instead.  Also learned that `article` has `\listoffigures`.

Derp. Oh well.

Comment: `fixltx2e` makes several other things robust as well. See this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/why-and-were-not-defined-as-robust-commands-in-the-first-place).

Comment: @TH. self-accepting is only available 48h after the question has been posted.

Comment: @Caramdir: Oh. Well, in that case, he should accept in 38 hours.