# Must I include \begin{math} every time I want to enter a symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am using the following syntax in my document's preamble :

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Question is, must I use `\begin{math} \*symbol* \end{math]` every time I type in a symbol ? Or am I missing an easier way to insert symbols ?

I tried looking online before posting but haven't found an answer.

Comment: Are you concerned with math-related symbols? If so, using either `$<symbol macro>$` or `\(<symbol macro>\)` will work. There also plenty text-mode symbols; for those, it's not necessary to enter math mode.

Comment: @Mico Suggested by OP to be an answer. I am rather young here, so I am afraid that I can act against the rules, when I incorporate your comment into my answer, as suggested by NLed.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke - Not to worry: Just augment your answer, per the OP's suggestion, to mention the `\( ... \)` method.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke you could also mention that `$...$` is robust, but `\(...\)` is fragile.

Comment: It's encouraging, in a way, to see that someone, at least, seems to be learning LaTeX from a source that completely eschews plain TeX constructs; it's too easy to learn a muddle of deprecated hacks from internet references.  The question is, what source would consider `\begin{math}` to be the sole math-mode delimiter?  That's just perverse.

Comment: @RyanReich An example (text in Polish) "Do trybu matematycznego wewnątrzakapitowego przechodzimy używając
otoczenia math. Na przykład kod \begin{math} x^2 \end{math} kompiluje
się jako x^2. Zamiast \begin{math} można pisać skrótowo \( lub $." In short: "$ may be used INSTEAD OF `\begin{math}`". Horrible!

Comment: Highly related: [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510)

Comment: Also related: [`Why \( and \) were not defined as robust commands in the first place?`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14257/3954)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can use `$...$`; for example, `$\heartsuit$`. Another simple method -- also mentioned in @Mico's comment -- is to use `\(...\)`: `\( \heartsuit \)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You might want to add what Mico posted above too for other people to see.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to streamline the reference to the `\( ... \)` method. :-)