# What is Math Mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm new to TeX and tried to enter an equation using `\mathbb`. I received a prompt

```
LaTeX Error: \mathbb allowed only in math mode.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

I thought I would try here for an explanation.

Comment: Phil's answer below is correct, but a further tip: the macro `\mathbb` typesets capital letters as "black-board bold" symbols, such as the symbol ℝ which usually denotes the set of real numbers (and which is produced by `\mathbb{R}` in math mode).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You enter math mode by typing a dollar sign `$`, and you leave math mode by typing another dollar sign `$`.  You should take a look at Chapter 3 of [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

I guess that an even better way to enter math mode is to use `\(` and `\)`, as discussed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to/513#513).

Answer (score 6):

`TeX` knows several modes, two of them are math mode and display math mode. Typesetting of ordinary text such as words nor numbers is different compared to mathematical formulas or a mathematical identifier such as *`x`*, which should look different from the text `x` (it does differ here in this editor only vaguely)

In order to let `TeX` know which mode should be used, there are indicators to enter math mode:

- Inline math mode, being entered `$` and closed with `$`
- Display math mode, used with an enclosing `$$...$$` in plain `TeX` or with `\[...\]` in `LaTeX`
- Typing inside `\begin{math}...\end{math}` in `LaTeX`
- Several math environments in `LaTeX` enter the math mode automatically, such as `equation`, `align`, `alignedat`, `gather` etc.

Several characters/symbols being connected to math content require entering the math mode, such as `\mathbb{R}` etc.