# Missing $ error with matrix

Tags: math-mode, errors, matrices

The code below produces the mistake in the picture. Any idea why?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Above is the minimal example. I have not given the all code because the error is related to matrix. So, other packages are needed for the rest of the code. What do you mean by math-mode?

Comment: some "math" environments can stand alone, for example `equation` and `align`.  others have to be embedded in an explicitly math environment.  if this is meant as a display, then wrapping it in `\[ ... \]` or the `equation` environment would be appropriate.

Comment: You might also find this answer helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/what-is-math-mode.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix environments of the `amsmath` package have to be set in math mode. You didn't do that, thus TeX is searching for some `$` which enables this math mode. If you put it in `$...$`, `\(...\)`, `\[...\]`, `\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}`, `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` or `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`, (and most certainly others...,) it will work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d
    \end{bmatrix}\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do it with documentclass "standalone"? I need it to create small graphs.  But it seems \bmatrix doesn't work there.

Comment: @skan https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518273/cant-create-multiline-matrix-with-standalone