# Can't create multiline matrix with standalone?

Tags: align, matrices

I want to split matrix over two lines using `align` environment. But I couldn't compile source code with message `! missing \endgroup inserted.`. I found out this works well on other class, such as `article`. Is there any idea to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\everymath{\displaystyle} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
    2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `standalone`, use `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$`. It's `align` which is faulty.

Comment: Add option `varwidth` to `standalone` and you'll see why @Bernard suggests `$...$` + `aligned`

Comment: wow. thanks!! I've realized many things. I've been using settings as `mathindent` to prevent margin. :-(

Comment: The align environment uses the whole width, but standalone doesn't have a width to fill.  At least, not without varwidth or a minipage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that is not entirely true, it always starts at the left edge of the text block, but it only extends to the widest part of the display. Isn't the problem here rather that standalone does not have a defined text width and thst breaks align

Comment: @JohnKormylo interesting, then that is not the whole truth.

Comment: @daleif - The odd thing is that \textwidth etc. are defined (345pt) but not used.  Perhaps everything is put inside an \hbox.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved with the comments.

Comment: @daleif -- The information that `standalone` doesn't have a width is useful, but I can't find another question where this is clearly explained.  Please add an answer.