# problem with underline using babel

Tags: babel, unicode, hebrew

My latex document is in hebrew and english 
those are my headers :

```
\documentclass[greek, english, hebrew]{article} % <- here
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english, hebrew]{babel} % <- and here
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

and when I try to

```
\underline{x^2}
```

I'm getting those errors:

> Missing $ inserted. $\underline{x^2} 
>   Missing } inserted. $\underline{x^2} 
>   Missing $ inserted. $\underline{x^2} 
>   Missing } inserted. $\underline{x^2} 
>   Missing $ inserted. $\underline{x^2} 
>   Missing $ inserted. $\underline{x^2} 
>   Extra }, or forgotten $. $\underline{x^2} 
>   Extra }, or forgotten $. $\underline{x^2}

without

```
\usepackage[greek, english, hebrew]{babel}
```

underline works but hebrew not

any tips?
thanks!

Comment: Update changed to use polyglossia [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202194/babel-for-hebrew)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/44572)

Comment: The usage of `^` as a shortcut for superscript does (almost) only make sense in [math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346536/134144). The errors you describe occur because you used `^`  outside of math mode.