# An Error in Math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors

What is the meaning of

```
\mathcal allowed only in math mode
```

What sign should I use to fix this error?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Here there is the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/what-is-math-mode

Comment: It denotes the *math calligraphic font*, and as its name suggests, it is reserved for mathematics. There exists calligraphic fonts that can be used in text mode (`rsfs` or `brushscript`, for instance), and you can use them if you load the relevant package.

Comment: You probably have something like `blah blah \mathcal{A} blah blah` in your text. Instead you should have `blah blah $\mathcal{A}$ blah blah`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the reason of the mistake of the OP is cited by last comment.