# what is the meaning of "\(" and "\)" in overleaf?

Tags: syntax

In overleaf tutorial https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands,

```
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

The set of real numbers are usually represented 
by a blackboard bold capital r: \( \R \).
```

I know the usage of newcommand, but what is necessity of of `\(` and `\)`?

Comment: Please look at [What is Math Mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15662/82917) and [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/82917)

Comment: `\(...\)` is similar to `$...$` but can provide better error messages if either `\(` or `\)` is missing

Comment: In the same tutorial, have a look at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are \‌( and \‌) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode)