# How is missing $ inserted?

Tags: math-mode, errors, compiling, compilation-error, missing

Here's a line of erroneous code.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\frac{a}{M}
\end{document}
```

As we expect, the compiler throws a "missing $" error.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.91 \frac{a}{M}
                
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

My question is: **how** are the missing `$` inserted?

I expect that the system would insert `$` at both the start and the end of line, so that the compiler would give

[image]

However, the compiler actually gave me this.

[image]

I dont't understand why the first token list `{a}` of the `\frac` command was interpreted as text.

When I try math mode only commands, the first token list would be interpreted in math mode.  For example, `frac{\sqrt2}{M}` gives this.

[image]

Comment: First, the class should be standalonE not standalon

Comment: nice catch my bad.  lemme fix that.

Comment: My explanation: `\frac` expands to `\begingroup #1\endgroup \over #2`. The `a` (in `#1`) doesn't need math-mode so it doesn't trigger the error but `\over` does → `a $\over M $`. But with `\sqrt` this gets triggered twice: at the `\sqrt` and then at the `\over`. Compare `\begingroup \sqrt{2} \endgroup a` vs `\sqrt{2} a`. But I'm sure there is more to say about whatever TeX is doing deep down.

Comment: I've explained in some detail a very similar issue in an answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575988/82917

Comment: @campa re-open that one? (closed as solved in comments is never a good reason)

Comment: The difference with the question marked as duplicate is that `a` is legal in text mode, but `\sqrt{2}` isn't.