# Overleaf math mode misplacing bug?

Tags: math-mode, overleaf

Not sure how to describe my problem since the situation is weird . Recently I found that Overleaf would automatically "misplace" the math mode  . For example
" $ \lim_{ n \to \infty} a_n $ " will become " lim n→∞  an \lim_{n \to infty} a_n " , the dollar symbol is removed and the symbols are copied pasted . I'm sure
this is not typo becuse it happens so frequently . Did anyone also encounter this problem ?

Here is a part of my code (automatically misplaced version)

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{CJKutf8}
 \usepackage{amsmath} 
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage{amssymb} 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \title{AP exercise ch10}
 \date{}
 \begin{document}
 \maketitle\noindent
 \textbf{Exercise 10.1.4} \\
 We observe that if x<12x < \frac{1}{2} , ψ(x)=2x<1\psi(x) = 2x < 1 
 and if 12<x<1 \frac{1}{2} < x < 1 , ψ(x)=2x−1\psi(x) = 2x - 1 .
 So for any [a,b]⊂[0,1)[a,b] \subset [ 0 , 1 ) , we separate 
 ψ−1([a,b])\psi^{-1}([a,b]) into
 two parts i.e 
\begin{align*}
 \psi^{-1}( [ a , b ] ) \cap [0 , \frac{1}{2} ) & =
\{ x \in [ 0 , 1 ) \; \rvert \;
x < \frac{1}{2} \; , \; x \in
[ \frac{a}{2}  , \frac{b}{2}] \}
= [\frac{a}{2} , \frac{b}{2}] 
\\
\psi^{-1}( [ a , b ] ) \cap (\frac{1}{2} , 1 ) &= 
\{ x \in [ 0 , 1 ) \; \rvert \;
\frac{1}{2} < x < 1 \; , \; x \in
[ \frac{1+a}{2}  , \frac{1+b}{2}] \}
= [\frac{1+a}{2} , \frac{1+b}{2}]
\end{align*}
Hence $\mu(\psi^{-1}([a,b])) =
\mu( [\frac{a}{2} , \frac{b}{2} ])
+ \mu([\frac{1+a}{2} , \frac{1+b}{2}] ) = b- a = \mu([b,a])$ .
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you show an example? A minimal one. If not, it is difficult to help.

Comment: overleaf hosts a texlive system but the output is standard latex processing, and you would get the same result from a local tex system. If you show your input tex code someone will explain the output

Comment: Please post the code itself, not a screeenshot of the code.

Comment: Sorry , let me edit it agian

Comment: you are using math consructs like `^` and `\in`  in text, surely you get multiple  errors from that input? The pdf is not intended to be usable after any error

Comment: The code is misplaced version . I'm very sure I put them in math mode properly . But it automatically become like this after I opened the document again .

Comment: `x<12x < \frac{1}{2}` should be `$x<12x < \frac{1}{2}$` for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a simple fraction not displaying properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575988/why-is-a-simple-fraction-not-displaying-properly)

Comment: I know . But somehow Overleaf automatically removed the dollar symbols in the source code . Sometimes this happens when I open the document .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I don't think this posting is a duplicate, as the OP's issues seem to stem from some browser settings that combine to have some very odd consequences. Not being much of an Overleaf user myself, my main recommendation to the OP is to ask the Overleaf help desk for, well, help.

Comment: I only use Overleaf for latex texting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you really need to check your browser settings: Not only have lots of instances of `$` gone missing, but there are also (at least) six instances -- in just the code fragment you've posted -- of inline math expressions having been "doubled up". E.g., `ψ(x)=2x<1` is prefixed to `\psi(x) = 2x < 1`, `12<x<1` is prefixed to `\frac{1}{2} < x < 1`, etc.

Not being much on Overleaf user myself, all I can suggest is that you contact their helpdesk directly and ask them for assistance in fixing your browser settings.

Anyway, after supplying the missing instances of `$`, commenting out the funky code doublets, and addressing other, slightly odd aspects of your code -- e.g., by replacing `\; \rvert \;` with `\bigm\vert` -- one is left with the following code, which may be close to what you actually want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
 \usepackage{CJKutf8} % are you sure you need this?
 \usepackage{amsmath} 
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage{amssymb} 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{Exercise 10.1.4}

\noindent
We observe that if 
%x<12  %% huh?! #1
$x < \frac{1}{2}$, 
%ψ(x)=2x<1  %% huh?! #2
$\psi(x) = 2x < 1$ 
and if 
%12<x<1   %% huh?! #3
$\frac{1}{2} < x < 1$, 
%ψ(x)=2x−1  %% huh?! #4
$\psi(x) = 2x - 1$.
So for any 
%[a,b]⊂[0,1)  %% huh?! #5
$[a,b] \subset [ 0 , 1 )$, 
we separate 
%ψ−1([a,b])  %% huh?! #6
$\psi^{-1}([a,b])$ 
into two parts, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\psi^{-1}( [ a , b ] ) \cap \bigl[0 , \tfrac{1}{2} \bigr) 
&=
\bigl\{ x \in [ 0 , 1 ) 
%\; \rvert \; 
\bigm\vert
0 < x < \tfrac{1}{2} 
%\; , \; 
,\ x \in
  \bigl[ \tfrac{a}{2} , \tfrac{b}{2}\bigr] \bigr\}
= \bigl[ \tfrac{a}{2} , \tfrac{b}{2}\bigr] 
\\
\psi^{-1}( [ a , b ] ) \cap \bigl(\tfrac{1}{2} , 1 \bigr) 
&= 
\bigl\{ x \in [ 0 , 1 ) 
%\; \rvert \;
\bigm\vert
\tfrac{1}{2} < x < 1 
%\; , \; 
,\ x \in
  \bigl[ \tfrac{1+a}{2} , \tfrac{1+b}{2}\bigr] \bigr\}
= \bigl[ \tfrac{1+a}{2} , \tfrac{1+b}{2}\bigr]
\end{align*}
Hence $\mu\bigl(\psi^{-1}([a,b])\bigr) =
\mu\bigl( \bigl[\frac{a}{2} , \frac{b}{2} \bigr]\bigr)
+ \mu\bigl(\bigl[\frac{1+a}{2} , \frac{1+b}{2}\bigr] \bigr) 
= b- a = \mu([b,a])$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'll check what's wrong abot the browser setting

Comment: Now I find the reason . Really like what you said , this because I install the plugin "Tex All The Things" , which will convert latex codes into math symbols .

Comment: @std92050 - Thanks for this update. So glad you were able to get to the bottom of this issue.