# Why doesn't lineno number a paragraph when it is followed by an indented equation?

Tags: equations, amsmath, line-numbering

While searching for the source of missing line numbers, I realized that paragraphs followed immediately by an equation have no line number, but this is fixed when a space is included,

e.g. the following document has no line numbers:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit: 
$$1+1=2$$ 
\end{document}
```

But this one does:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit: 

$$1+1=2$$ 
\end{document}
```

The only difference is the space above the equation.

- Why is this the case (and is there a simple workaround)?
- Is it incorrect to include an indented equation in a paragraph, or is this just a 'feature' of `lineno`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$$...$$` is obsolete, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503). If you use the correct LaTeX displayed math environment, the numbering works without the empty line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit: 
\[1+1=2\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, is `$` also obsolete?

Comment: @David: that's true, see: [Are `\( and \)` preferable to $](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to). At least: `\( ... \)` is LaTeX syntax, so better supported in LaTeX. `$...$` is plain TeX. However, usually both work well, many prefer `$...$` because it's easier to write or just classic.

Comment: @David: `\(` and `\)` are fragile by default. So, as [Will Robertson said](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to/542#542), don't use them unless you use `fixltx2e` package. And the default `\(` and `\)` have very few advantages compared with `$`.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, what could I do if I need numbered equations?

Comment: @Sigur Use an `equation` environment.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, thanks. I noticed this problem when I tried to use the stared version of `equation`. So with `equation` both lines above and below are numbered except the line with the equation contents which has its equation number in parenthesis. If I use `equation*` to remove the equation number, then the line above the equation has no number and the line below has.

Answer (score 33):

For line numbering to be done correctly the math environments has to be wrapped using the `\begin{linenomath*}` and `\end{linenomath*}` code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
For line numbering to be done correctly the math environments has to be wrapped using the ''linenomath`` code as follows: 

\begin{linenomath*}
    \begin{equation}
        a^2=b^2+c^2
    \end{equation}
\end{linenomath*}
some text here some text here  some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text heresome text here. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is particularly valuable, because it works for the AMS align environment, too!

Comment: What's the difference between having `linenomath` and not having `linenomath`?

Answer (score 24):

Mathematics environments need to be wrapped by `\begin{linenomath*}` and `\end{linenomath*}` as mentioned in [Bamzi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244372/95441).

A quick way to change all your equations is to renew the equation environment by adding the code

```
\let\oldequation\equation
\let\oldendequation\endequation

\renewenvironment{equation}
  {\linenomathNonumbers\oldequation}
  {\oldendequation\endlinenomath}
```

before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I'd say this is the most convenient answer. Thanks!

Comment: This answer should be upvoted to top. Definitely.

Comment: How do we apply lineno with `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` The above does not seem to work for me for unsing `lineno` on paragraphs where I have unnumbered equations.

Answer (score 3):

As @Denis has said, the `mathlines` option can be used in some cases (for `article`, but not for `iopart`, for example). If you do so, and you are also using the `amsmath` package, be sure to load `lineno` after `amsmath`. Sometimes other packages load `amsmath`, be aware of that; you can check the log file to see this.  This MWE can be used to easily see the effect of that change:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}

\begin{document}
    \linenumbers

    Line number

    No line number if lineno is loaded before amsmath!
    \begin{equation}
        x = y
    \end{equation}

    Line number
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `mathlines` option for lineno and write:

```
\begin{linenomath}
\begin{align*}
z_{1}&=x_{1}+y_{1}\\
z_{2}&=x_{2}+y_{2}
\end{align*}
\end{linenomath}
```

to obtain

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Stefan Pinnow fixed the equation command. Use this to fix the align command in the same style:

```
\let\oldalign\align
\let\oldendalign\endalign

\renewenvironment{align}
  {\linenomathNonumbers\oldalign}
  {\oldendalign\endlinenomath}
```

Comment: Your answer is basically a duplicateof R.M asnwer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404726/224762)

Comment: How do we apply lineno with `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` The above does not seem to work for me for using lineno on paragraphs where I have unnumbered equations

Comment: @Roland no it's not, this answer says explicitely that it is to fix the align command