# Missing some lines in adding line number of latex

Tags: numbering, lineno

I have used "lineno" package with "switch" and "pagewise" options to add line number in my document. But there is an interesting problem. Some lines in the documents have not been numbered. Could please help me? 
[image]

Comment: Please do not post your code as screen shot, but add a small, ready-to-be-copied example. This will help the people, who are trying to help you.

Comment: Dear, I just used

\usepackage[ switch, pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\leftlinenumbers

in preamble and body of my document is a normal text.

Comment: But this does not show us your actual problem. A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) could make the question answerable, at the moment we can only guess. Section 3.3 from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/lineno.pdf might help, but that's just a guess.

Comment: It looks like this occurs when there are equations - which is a known issue. The documentation for lineno outlines how to use this package so that paragraphs with displayed equations are numbered.

Comment: Most likely duplicate of [amsmath - Why doesn't lineno number a paragraph when it is followed by an indented equation? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25784/why-doesnt-lineno-number-a-paragraph-when-it-is-followed-by-an-indented-equatio).