# Line numbers in paragraphs containing displayed equations and the graphbox and mathtools packages

Tags: lineno

I am using the packages `mathtools` and `graphbox`, and these seem to be interferring with `lineno` - numbers do not print for paragraphs that contain displayed equations.

This is similar to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25784/70816), however I am using `equation` environments. I have tried putting the line numbers call both before and after the offending packages with no change.

I haven't quite been able to reproduce the problem with an MWE - in the below MWE removing `mathtools` fixes the problem, in my main document this has no effect. If I remove both `mathtools` and `graphbox` it works, but I'd prefer not to loose graphbox unless I have to.

I'm not worried about numbering the lines with displayed equations, but I do want the text numbered.  Is there a simple work around?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[draft,12]{agujournal2018}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{url} %this package should fix any errors with URLs in refs.

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphbox}

\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\journalname{Journal Name}
\begin{document}
Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Urna neque viverra justo nec. At lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus at urna.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ConservationOfMass}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. Hac habitasse platea

\begin{figure}  \begin{center}
\includegraphics[height = 1cm,align=c]{example-image-a} \includegraphics[align=c,height = 1.6cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig}  \end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does using `\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}` help?  I don't have the class so can't test, but seemed to work when I switched to the `article` class.

Comment: @PeterGrill Unfortunately not - there's an option clash (not sure what with), and has no effect