# Error in built output

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors

This is difficult for me with all these $ signs. Now, where is the problem in the following MWE?

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\varphi_{nk}(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}
1 & $x_{k}\succ_{n} y_{k}$\\
1/2 & $x_{k} \sim_{n} y_{k}$\\
0 & $x_{k}\prec_{n} y_{k}$
\end{array}
\right.

So \textit{n} is \varphi_{n}(x,y)= \sum_{k}\varphi_{nk}


\end{document}
```

Also a more general question related to Tex.sx. How can I copy the code to the question box, without having to press space bar 4 times for each line to indent it?

As a follow up, in case I would like to insert the word 'if' in every case (piece) of the function above, how can I do so?
Eg

```
...1/2 & if $x_{k}\succ_{n} y_{k}$
```

doesn't seem to work as the 'if' is conjoined.

Comment: Re "question box" (code sample):  Highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: For questions about the site, please visit [meta].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `$` within an array environment, since the array environment is completely in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\begin{document}
\[
\varphi_{nk}(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}
1 & x_{k}\succ_{n} y_{k}\\
1/2  x_{k} \sim_{n} y_{k}\\
0 & x_{k}\prec_{n} y_{k}
\end{array}
\right.
\]
So $n$ is $\varphi_{n}(x,y)= \sum_{k}\varphi_{nk}$.
\end{document}
```

Further tips regarding your example:

- Use math expressions such as `\varphi_{nk}(x,y)` in math mode, either within text (inline) such as by [`$...$` or `\( ... \)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to) or in displayed mode, such as by [`\[ ... \]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) in my example.
- Don't use empty lines before or after such displayed math formulas.
- Don't use `\textit` for simulating math mode.

Have a look at the [Mathmode tag wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathmode/info) for links to tutorials, useful packages and resources on this site.

Answer (score 4):

You should read [Math mode (H. Voß)](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). With `$...$` you always use the inline math.

You example can be modified with the `cases`-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\varphi_{nk}(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}
1 & x_{k}\succ_{n} y_{k}\\
1/2 & x_{k} \sim_{n} y_{k}\\
0 & x_{k}\prec_{n} y_{k}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
So \textit{n} is$ \varphi_{n}(x,y)= \sum_{k}\varphi_{nk}$


\begin{equation}
\varphi_{nk}(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x_{k}\succ_{n} y_{k}\\
1/2 & x_{k} \sim_{n} y_{k}\\
0 & x_{k}\prec_{n} y_{k}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
So \textit{n} is$ \varphi_{n}(x,y)= \sum_{k}\varphi_{nk}$
\end{document}
```