# Which is the preferred command for equations in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, best-practices

While browsing some of the older questions I [learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) that I should not use `$$`. I also [learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to) that I blamed LaTeX for obscure error messages that can be prevented by using `\(` and `\)`. I started to further review my LaTeX files (old habits die hard) and now I have the following question:

Even if not using `$$`, there are many possible ways to get equations separated from the text. Which one should I use and why? `\begin{equation}`, `\[`, `\begin{eqnarray}` or some other?

I want to make the question more precise and ask for

- a. a one line equation with no label/number,
- b. a one line equation with a label/number,
- c. a multi line equation with no label/number,
- d. a multi line equation with one label/number and
- e. a multi line equation with one number/label for each line.

Could you please point out if a package is needed as well, but I would prefer to learn the 'pure' LaTeX macros/ environments, first.

Comment: [Avoid eqnarray!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen)

Comment: All your questions will be answered if you read the [mathmode by Herbert Voß](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in environments are `displaymath` for a single unnumbered equation, `equation` for a single numbered equation, and `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*` for multiple aligned equations with and without numbering, respectively. `\[` and `\]` are equivalent to `\begin{displaymath}` and `end{displaymath}`.

It is widely accepted that `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*` should not be used, because the spacing they create is inconsistent with all of the other environments (see [Avoid eqnarray](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) for details).

To generate aligned equations, one could use the `array` environment inside an `equation` or `displaymath` environment, but most people load the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), which provides many flexible environments for displayed equations. Note that amsmath creates an `equation*` environment for single unnumbered equations, which is syntactically more consistent than `displaymath`.

Comment: Let me see if I got everything: `\usepackage{amsmath}`. Then use (a) `\begin{equation*}`, (b) `\begin{equation}`, (c) `\begin{align*}`, (d) `\begin{equation}\begin{split}`, (e) `\begin{align}`

Comment: (a), (b) yes. For (c), (d) & (e) it depends on exactly what you want. I use `multline` and `multline*` for single equations that are too long for one line, and `align` and `align*` for multiple equations with an aligned symbol on each line (e.g. `=`). Of course amsmath provides much more than this --- just choose the environment that is best suited to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also note that using `\begin/end{equation*}` instead of `\[ ... \]` makes the code a lot easier to edit, and the start and end part are much easier to spot.