# How do I embed equations in the text?

Tags: math-mode, equations, paragraphs

Let's say I have a text block like this:

> Within the field of texture analysis, a number of categories of
>   methods exist, and even if we restrict ourselves to statistical
>   methods, a large number of methods are available. `\begin{equation}
>   f(x) = x + 3  \end{equation}` Statistical approaches are considered to
>   be generally applicable and work well for natural textures present in
>   images.

Here the `\begin{equation} f(x) = x + 3  \end{equation}` won't work. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use dollar symbols:

```
...a large number of methods are available. $f(x) = x + 3$ Statistical 
approaches are considered to be...
```

Note that equations should be part of a sentence. Also, you might like to read the [Not So Short Introcution to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english).

Answer (score 16):

While dollar signs work, it's better to use `\(` and `\)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Within the field of texture analysis, a number of categories of methods exist, and even
if we restrict ourselves to statistical methods, a large number of methods are
available. \( f(x) = x + 3 \) Statistical approaches are considered to be generally
applicable and work well for natural textures present in images.
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the reasoning behind that and more information, see [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to). In this thread, Will Robertson suggests that you should [only use this syntax in combination with the `fixltx2e` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542/4012).

Furthermore, I agree with Ian: In-line equations should be properly embedded in the sentence structure.