# How I can write this equation in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image: Image of equation]

I’m still a beginner to LaTeX, and I don’t know how to write this equation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I embed equations in the text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42937/how-do-i-embed-equations-in-the-text)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It sounds as if you need an introductory text about LaTeX to lay out its basic principals and capabilities.

Comment: the answers to this question might be useful: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/579)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Welcome to the site. We will appreciate the questions that have a minimal working example (code) that shows the efforts you have already put. Asking somebody to do things is frowned upon here. If you have no idea of how to start, you may put the following as a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  %equation here
\end{document}
```

and ask for the equation code. Since this is your first question, here is the code for the equation you requested and this should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  %% gives more goodies for typing mathematics
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \hat{b}_k = \frac{2\tau - \Delta_k}{2\tau + \Delta_k}\hat{b}_{k-1} + \frac{\Delta_k}{2\tau + \Delta_k}(b_k + \hat{b}_{k-1})
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you harish kumar from now if i want anything i will do my best then i will ask if i need help thank you again

Comment: i tried to write this equation but appear there is a wrong

Comment: \begin{equation}
 K = \[\sqrt[3]{\fra{W_max}{\left (\beta /C)}}
\end{equation}

Comment: @osama: `\begin{equation} K = \sqrt[3]{\frac{W_{\max}}{\left(\beta /C\right)}} \end{equation}` Note `\frac` instead of `\fra` and `\max` instead of `max`. Also you need to balance `\left(` with `\right)`

Comment: my friend can i send you my paper i need to submit it today i just need to help to add some images i tried many times but there still some wrongs i hope if i can chat with you private

Comment: @osama: Adding a picture should be simple using `\includegraphics` command from `graphicx` package. Better ask a new question here instead of sending the paper to me.