# multline inside an item

Tags: lists, enumerate, multline

Is there a way to use a `multline` inside an `\item` element of `enumerate` WITHOUT a new line between the index of list and the formula?

```
 \begin{enumerate}[i.]
    \item $checkorder( (\lambda,\lambda,\lambda) ) \triangleq true$
    \item \begin{multline*}$$
     checkorder( (a,(u,U_1,U_2),(v,V_1,V_2)) ) \triangleq \\
     (u = \lambda \vee u \leq_A a) \wedge
     (v = \lambda \vee a \leq_A v) \wedge \\
     checkorder(U_1) \, \wedge checkorder(U_2) \wedge
     checkorder(V_1) \wedge checkorder(V_2)$$
     \end{multline*}
    \item $checkorder(T) \triangleq false$ negli altri casi
 \end{enumerate}
```

this is what i have: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udBX4.png]

and this is what i would want: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kv8M.png]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `amsmath` alignment environments are only for display math. But `mathtools` augments the available environments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumerate,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[i.]
    \item $\mathit{checkorder}( (\lambda,\lambda,\lambda) ) \triangleq \mathit{true}$
    \item $\begin{multlined}[t]
     \mathit{checkorder}( (a,(u,U_1,U_2),(v,V_1,V_2)) ) \triangleq \\
     (u = \lambda \vee u \leq_A a) \wedge
     (v = \lambda \vee a \leq_A v) \wedge {} \\
     \mathit{checkorder}(U_1) \wedge \mathit{checkorder}(U_2) \wedge
     \mathit{checkorder}(V_1) \wedge checkorder(V_2)
     \end{multlined}$
    \item $\mathit{checkorder}(T) \triangleq \mathit{false}$ negli altri casi
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice a couple of refinements: long function names should be inside `\mathit`, to get a better looking font in this case; the `\wedge` before `\\` should be followed by `{}` to get correct spacing.

*Never* use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: See [Why is `\[...\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/). On this site appreciation for an answer is expressed by clicking on the upper arrow besides the text; usually, after a delay to see if other more useful answers come along, one accepts the better one.

Comment: +1 By the same rational, is it not more preferable to use `\(...\)` instead of `$...$` I reference Joseph Wright's comments in [Are \( and \) preferable to $?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with `\multline` environment. So I came up with a forced solution. Here is what I did:

```
\item \abovedisplayskip-15pt 
      \belowdisplayskip\abovedisplayskip
      \begin{setlength}{\multlinegap}{0pt}
         \begin{multline*}
           2(x^2y-2xy^3+6xy)-3(-5xy+3x^2y\\-7xy^3)
            +5(xy^3-xy+x^2y)
      \end{multline*}
      \end{setlength}
```

Of course, egreg's solution is by far the best and mine is was just out of desperation in finding an immediate solutions. I know that my code above is not the best but hey it solved my problem. I have decided to implement egreg's answer into my code as it seems to better and more concise.