# Emacs and latex math delimiters

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex

The `forward-sexp` command in EMACS can be used to find the `$` that closes an inline equation: if the point is before the `$` that opens the equation, then `forward-sexp` moves the point after the closing `$`. This does the correct thing with nested equations: e.g., if the point is before `$a + \text{b $c$}$`, then `forward-sexp` moves the point past the entire equation. Is there a way to find the `\)` or `\]` that closes a `\(` and `\[` with auctex, perhaps with `texmathp` or `font-latex-match-math-env`? This seems to be a bit tricky in EMACS as there is no way to store multi-char delimiters in a syntax table.

Comment: I would not bother: `$`...`$`, as opposed to `\(`...`\)`, is reliably robust in macro arguments and when written to files (i.e., table of contents), and `\begin{equation*}`...`\end{equation*}` (using amsmath package) is quite better visible.

Comment: @DavidKastrup [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510)

Comment: As I already said: I would not bother with `\(` `\)` `\[` `\]`.  The theoretic gain of matched delimiters is not worth the price in editing support and loss of robustness in LaTeX.

Comment: @DavidKastrup But many people use [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) which redefines them as robust.

Comment: @N.N. I finally saw this discussion today; it is precisely the lack of support for matching these delimiters in EMACS that has kept me using `$` in LaTeX. I have some macros to quickly switch equations between inline and displayed that make critical use of `forward-sexp`.

Comment: @DavidKastrup: `\( .. \)` is nice and robust as well when one does `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`

Answer (score 6):

I have put together a function that might do what you want. It searches for the next LaTeX math delimiter – `\(`, `\)`, `\[` or `\]` – while ignoring comments and if is an opening delimiter it tries to find its matching delimiter.

```lisp
(defun forward-latex-math ()
  "Move forward across the next LaTeX equation. It is meant work like `forward-sexp' but for LaTeX math delimiters."
  (interactive)
  (let ((count 1))
    ;; Search for either of the following \( \) \[ \]
    (re-search-forward-ignore-TeX-comments "\\\\(\\|\\\\)\\|\\\\\\[\\|\\\\]")
    (cond
     ;; If the search hits \(
     ((looking-back "\\\\(" (- (point) 2))
      (while (< 0 count)
        ;; Search for delimiters inside the equation
        (re-search-forward-ignore-TeX-comments "\\\\(\\|\\\\)")
        (if (looking-back "\\\\(" (- (point) 2))
            (setq count (1+ count))     ; If start of a nested level
          (setq count (1- count))))     ; If end of a nested level
      ;; Find the matching \)
      (re-search-forward "\\\\)" (eobp) t count))
     ;; If the search hits \[
     ((looking-back "\\\\\\[" (- (point) 2))
      (while (< 0 count)
        ;; Search for delimiters inside the equation
        (re-search-forward-ignore-TeX-comments "\\\\\\[\\|\\\\]")
        (if (looking-back "\\\\\\[" (- (point) 2))
            (setq count (1+ count))     ; If start of a nested level
          (setq count (1- count))))     ; If end of a nested level
      ;; Find the matching \]
      (re-search-forward "\\\\]" (eobp) t count)))))

(defun re-search-forward-ignore-TeX-comments (regexp)
  "Search for REGEXP and ignore TeX comments. Used by `forward-latex-math'."
  (re-search-forward regexp (eobp) t)
  ;; If in comment search to after it
  (while (TeX-in-comment)
    (forward-line)
    (re-search-forward regexp (eobp) t)))
```

To use it place it in your .emacs and run it by <kbd>M-x</kbd>`forward-latex-math`. If you want to use it often you might want to bind it to key.

Since I have just started to learn Lisp I am sure this code can improved in many ways. Please comment if you have any suggestions.

Comment: This doesn't deal with commented-out delimiters correctly. It's not clear to me that these delimiters can be properly matched without reimplementing LaTeX.

Comment: @SamuelIsaacson How should it deal with commented out delimiters?

Comment: This code matches `\( % \)` as a single unit, but it shouldn't; it should continue searching on the next line to find the closing `\)`.

Comment: @SamuelIsaacson I have updated the function to ignore comments. Let me know if it does not work as you want.