# vim-latex with strange (unwanted) highlighting

Tags: highlighting, vim

I'm using vim with the `latex-suite` package installed on Ubuntu 11.10 to edit LaTeX files.  The `latex-suite` highlights the LaTeX source as I edit it, but it seems to get very confused after something like `$\sigma_{\{x,y\}}$`.  The LaTeX code is correct; it compiles and displays fine, but highlighting after this symbol is very strange.  I tried to post a picture of what I get, but apparently new users can't post pictures.  Here is some example code which causes problems for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This text appears normally.  $\sigma_{\{x,y\}}$

But this text is highlighted very strangely.
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this?  As it is, I'd say the highlighting scheme in vim-latex is a little aggressive; I could do with something quite a bit simpler (e.g. one color for text, one for math, and one for environment declarations like `\begin{environementName}` and `\end{environmentName}`).

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the `latex-suite`. You can work around this using `\(` and `\)` to enter math mode, which is the [recommended way](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to/513#513).

Comment: Ah! Thank you.  That at least localizes the problem to the math-mode area, and makes the rest of my document readable. The slash before the left-brace is still orange, so something is still not quite right, but it's much better now.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is a bug of Ubuntu 11.*. I guess there are some problems with some libraries. However cmhughes tested your example under Ubuntu 10.04 without these odd highlighting. I tested your example under 11.10 and was able to reproduce this behaviour. Now I tested the same example under Ubuntu 12.04 and the bug seems to be fixed. I get the correct result.

[image]