# \emph in math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors, emphasis

I am new to LaTeX and have a problem with the line

```
The difference is that the signing key \emph{x} is split into two pieces, \begin{math}
\emph{x_{L}}\end{math} and \begin{math}\emph{x_{R}}\end{math} and are both elements of the 
\begin{math}\textbf{Z}_{q}\end{math}.
```

I get the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
```

I am a little confused why I am getting this error since I have put the `_` in a `math` section.  Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `\emph` is a text-mode command, so even though it's within a math-mode environment, a `_` will be recognized as text.  in fact, unless you've done something unusual, the math will be set automatically in italic, so there should be no need for the `\emph`.  also, a shorter way to input in-line math is `\( x_L \)` and you don't need to bury single-letter subscripts in braces.  these things will come with time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inline math you should use `$ your equation $`  or `\( your equation \)`. But `\(...\)`  is fragile. loading `fixltx2e` makes it robust. For display equation without number, use `\[ equation \]` or

```
\begin{equation*}
.
.
.
\end{equation*}
```

For numbered equations, use

```
\begin{equation}
.
.
.
\end{equation}
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
The difference is that the signing key $x$ is split into two pieces, 
$x_{L}$ and \(x_{R}\) and are both elements of the $x_{L}$

\[\mathbf{Z}_{q}.\]

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{Z}_{q}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{Z}_{q}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\(` ...`\)` is robust if you load `fixltx2e`.

Answer (score 7):

`\emph{}` starts in text mode, so its parameter must be text, not math. So you need to go into math mode again within the `\emph{}`, as in `\emph{$x_{L}$}`.

[image]

### Notes:

- I usually just use `$...$` for inline math constructs (See References below).
- Also I am not sure why you want to use `\emph{}` within math mode, unless you have a special definition of `\emph{}`.
- I have also replaced `\textbf{}` with `\mathbf{}`.

### References:

- You should review Herbert Voss's  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).
- Inline Math: [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to)
- Display Math: [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  The difference is that the signing key $x$ is split into two pieces, 
  $x_{L}$ and $x_{R}$ and are both elements of the $\mathbf{Z}_{q}$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `\emph{}` for math?

`$x_L$` and `$\mathbf{Z}_q$` will do the same in simplest form without error.

Comment: It looks like this is the only answer actually answering the implicit question (implied by the title, as the question is not clear): *how to emphasize math in latex*. +1. That said `mathbf` [renders poorly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKqCb.png), but that's not your fault!