# How to make the limit (mathematics) sign?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to learn how to make the limit sign. For example, take 'Limit of f(x) as x approaches 2 is 5' , how to make this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You are looking for `\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 5`. This has to be used in math mode which can be either **inline** mode (where the limit is placed as a subscript so that the inter line spacing of the paragraph is not perturbed):

[image]

or in **display** mode where the limits are placed underneath):

[image]

### References:

- For the two types of math modes, please see:

  1. Display Math: [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)
  2. Inline Math: [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to)
- An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
With in line mode this is typeset as $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 5$

\medskip
In display mode it is typset differently:
\[ \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 5 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: $ \lim_{x\to 2} f(x) $

Comment: @ZafarS: Well that is if you want to use it in inline math. In display math, the `$` is not used. The MWE should clarify that.  If it is still not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Nice answer but it’s slightly odd that your example uses `$…$` yet then you go on to refer to the question “Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?”

Comment: You can get the same effect in inline mode (as in the display mode) if you use `$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} f(x)=5$`.

Comment: @Sony: Good point, but usually better to _not_ do that in inline mode as that disturbs the interline spacing.  Thought about adding that to the answer but decided against it for that reason.

Comment: On 19/03/2021 - Link to Herbert Voss' comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX broken

Comment: @EnderWiggins: Thanks. Has been corrected.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use:

```
$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}$
```

It's in the **inline** mode, plus the limit is placed **underneath**.

Comment: `\displaystyle` does not take an argument; remove those braces, and note that this will also change the size of symbols such as summation and fractions.

Comment: It's better to use `$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}$` for such a case.

Comment: @egreg: What would a better suggestion that does not mess with line spacings and size of symbols?

Comment: @H.R. `\lim_{x\to\infty}`

Comment: @egreg I mean something like the display mode that does not mess with line spacing! :)

Comment: @H.R. As soon as you set the `x\to\infty` below “lim” you mess with the spacing. That's all.

Comment: @egreg: Is there a way to control the size of `x\to\infty` manually?

Comment: @H.R. Maybe if you make it so tiny as to be almost invisible…

Comment: This should have been the answer. It displays limits in the correct format since the approaches part of the limit shows directly below lim part rather than adjacent to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\Lim}{\displaystyle\lim}
\begin{document}
$\Lim_{x\to 1}(x-2)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has the same disadvantages as noted for the answer by @Greenhill. It's not a good idea to force adjacent lines to spread apart; in printed material, it looks bad and impedes reading.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use

```
\[ \stackrel{\mbox{lim}}{x \to 2} f(x) = 5 \]
```

Comment: But why bother with your own construction when the `\lim` macro is already defined?

Comment: I will perhaps cast my first downvote, here.

Comment: I’m so sorry, but I really had to do it, as the answer is truly misleading: a limit is definitely not a `\mathrel`.

Comment: I upvoted, purely because out of all the answers on this page, this is the only one that actually displays the `x \to 2` under the lim on my LMS.

Comment: Even though it is hacky, it might help someone else who is stuck.