# Labelling three-column array

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cross-referencing, arrays

I got this code:

```
$$\begin{array}{lcr}
a_{11}\cdot x_1+a_{12}\cdot x_2 &+ … + &a_{1n}\cdot x_n=\alpha_1 \\
a_{21}\cdot x_1+a_{22}\cdot x_2 &+…+&a_{2n}\cdot x_n=\alpha_2 \\
&\vdots & \\
a_{m1}\cdot x_1+a_{m2}\cdot x_2 &+…+&a_{mn}\cdot\ x_n=\alpha_m 
\end{array}$$
```

And I want to put a label outside to the right, giving the following PDF output:

```
Eq    =    my number
Eq2   =        umber  (2.2)
Eq3   =      two xer
```

How can I achieve this? It is important that the first column is left-aligned, the middle-column is centered, and the third-column is right-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an ordinary `equation`, which allows for the labelling:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{l@{}c@{}r}
    a_{11}\cdot x_1+a_{12}\cdot x_2 + \cdots + a_{1n}\cdot x_n & {}={} & \alpha_1 \\
    a_{21}\cdot x_1+a_{22}\cdot x_2 + \cdots + a_{2n}\cdot x_n & {}={} & \alpha_2 \\
    & \vdots & \\
    a_{m1}\cdot x_1+a_{m2}\cdot x_2 + \cdots + a_{mn}\cdot x_n & {}={} & \alpha_m
  \end{array} \label{myeqns}
\end{equation}
Here is some more text. See~(\ref{myeqns}).
\end{document}
```

The column specification `l@{}c@{}r` ensures a `l`eft, `c`entre, `r`ight alignment but also removes any inter-column space around the `c`-column. However, using `{}={}` corrects for the spacing around the `=`.

See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) and [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode) for more information on the use of LaTeX-style math delimiters (avoiding `$$`), unless you're using plain TeX (which would make this answer useless).

Comment: Wouldn't `aligned` be easier?

Comment: @egreg: But the alignment (rcl) would not be the way the OP requested (lcr).

Comment: Oops! Didn't see that. Then either `array` or `alignedat`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` rather than plain TeX style `$$`.

For equations that are not to be numbered you can use `\[` and `\]`, or, if the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is loaded, `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` You might find the answers to [Why is [ … ] preferable to $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2417) useful.