# Error using \( ... \) environment inside \section argument

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, table-of-contents

This seems to me like a possibly common problem, the solution of which is probably already been posted somewhere, unfortunately I'm not quite sure what key words i should use to find it.

Anyway, to the problem:
Something like this

```
\subsubsection{Spin-orbit coupling \( ciao \) }
```

will not usually pose a problem. However when i try to create a table of content with the

```
\tableofcontents
```

command i get the following error:

```
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {5.1.2}Spin-orbit coupling \relax $ ciao \relax \GenericError { }{LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter}{See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.}{Your command was ignored.\MessageBreak Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,\MessageBreak or <return> to continue without it.}}{8}{subsubsection.5.1.2}
```

The table of contents seems to not be the problem by itself, because when i do not use commands as the one shown above everything works fine.
Strangely enough, i can actually solve the problem by using instead of `\( stuff \)` the alternative `$stuff$`.
Now, is this supposed to work this way? or is it some sort of bug? or (more likely) am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `\(` and `\)` are not robust. If you add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` the error should disappear (you might need to compile twice or delete the `toc` file first).

Comment: @cgnieder Make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX's commands `\(` and `\)` are fragile commands per default which means they can cause an error in moving arguments such as sectioning commands in combination with `\tableofcontents`. The package [`fixltx2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) fixes this, as [Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/) mentions in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542/5049) to [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/5049)

Alternatively you can load [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (thanks to [@daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/)), load [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and robustify them yourself

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\(
\robustify\)
```

or protect them manually:

```
\subsubsection{Spin-orbit coupling \protect\( ciao \protect\) }
```

See also [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5049)

Comment: `mathtools` also robustify them, using the ideas from `fixltx2e` but without loading the extra stuff that may break packages.